# modifying a mysql table to show ranking based on column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm working on some code in php/MySql and I need to update a field called scorerank based on the score value.  I found a previous question here that addressed what I was looking for:

[Update the rank in a MySQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727138/update-the-rank-in-a-mysql-table/21638147#21638147)

I modified their example to work with my database.  I also added a condition so that I only modified columns that had a specific tourneyid and tableid.   I used a unique index variable in the inner join to id which row to update - I think I did it right, but I get the following error:

1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Here's my code.  Can anybody spot the error(s)?

```
UPDATE   tscores
JOIN     (SELECT    p.userid,p.scoreid,
                    IF(@lastPoint <> p.score, 
                       @curRank := @curRank + 1, 
                       @curRank)  AS rank,
                    IF(@lastPoint = p.score, 
                       @curRank := @curRank + 1, 
                       @curRank),
                    @lastPoint := p.score
          FROM      tscores p
          WHERE     (p.tourneyid=1 and p.tableid=2)
          JOIN      (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0) 
          ORDER BY  p.score DESC

         ) ranks ON (ranks.userid = tscores.userid)
SET      tscores.scorerank = ranks.scorerank
WHERE    tscores.scoreid = p.scoreid
```

Here's the table I'm working with:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tscores` (
  `scoreid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tourneyid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tableid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `score` int(16) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `scorestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `scoreround` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `scoregroup` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `scorerank` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`scoreid`),
  KEY `tourneyid` (`tourneyid`,`tableid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=62 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your last line you are trying to use an alias that is inside a subquery.. 
see the fix below

```
WHERE    tscores.scoreid = ranks.scoreid
```

Comment: i still get the same error with this:

    UPDATE   tscores
    ...
    SET      tscores.scorerank = ranks.scorerank
    WHERE    tscores.scoreid = ranks.scoreid

Comment: There are some markup that I don't understand there, I cannot be I can be any more helpful.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

one more attempt: try putting an alias (name or a leTTER) after this (i put mm)

```
JOIN      (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0) mm
```

Comment: is it possible this statement is in the wrong place?   WHERE     (p.tourneyid=1 and p.tableid=2)

Answer (score 0):

not that but swap the places of where and join join comes after from clause not after where
 change this ..

```
WHERE     (p.tourneyid=1 and p.tableid=2)
   JOIN      (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0)
```

to this

```
JOIN      (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0) 
WHERE     (p.tourneyid=1 and p.tableid=2)
```

and keep previous fixes as well

Comment: i am posting as a new answer because @ stuff wont allow me to put it because it thinks i am mentioning more than one person

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised version of your query:

```
UPDATE   tscores JOIN
         (SELECT    p.userid, p.scoreid,
                    IF(@lastPoint <> p.score, 
                       @curRank := @curRank + 1, 
                       @curRank)  AS rank,
                    @lastPoint := p.score
          FROM      tscores p CROSS JOIN
                    (SELECT @curRank := 0, @lastPoint := 0) const
          WHERE     (p.tourneyid = 1 and p.tableid = 2) 
          ORDER BY  p.score DESC
         ) ranks
         ON tscores.scoreid = p.scoreid 
    SET      tscores.scorerank = ranks.rank;
```

Here are changes:

1. Made the join condition on `scoreid`.  This is the primary key on `tscores` so that is all that is needed.
2. Removed the `where` clause and the redundant condition on `userid`.
3. Removed the second `if()` statement, which also incremented `@curRank`.
4. Changed the `JOIN` to a `CROSS JOIN`.  Without an `on` clause, you should use `CROSS JOIN` (even though MySQL does allow `JOIN` there).
5. Added a table alias for the assignment subquery.
6. Changed the `set` clause to refer to `rank` instead of `scorerank`.
7. Moved the assignment subquery *before* the `where` clause.