# Does mysql have the equivalent of Oracle's "analytic functions"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I'm looking for analytical function like `PARTITION BY` in MySQL (see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm#sthref964) for more info)

> Analytic functions compute an aggregate value based on a group of
>   rows. They differ from aggregate functions in that they return
>   multiple rows for each group.

Does it exist?

Comment: If this is like Windowing Functions, then no: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems

Comment: If you want windowing functions in an open source database you will need to use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<strike>No, it is one of the main lack of MySQL, compared to others DBMS like MSSQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL. I strongly doubt to see Window Functions in MySQL in any future, especially after Oracle acquisition of MySQL ...</strike>

**Update 04/2018**

MySQL 8.0 now supports [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: MySQL also lacks recursive queries

Comment: Am I missing something or is this article describing analytic functions for mysql: http://explainextended.com/2009/03/10/analytic-functions-first_value-last_value-lead-lag/ ????

Comment: Ah, now I understand, it is describing analytic functions and then describing how to achieve similar results without them in mysql ...

Answer (score 21):

just wanted to tell you that you can use variables in MySQL to mimic analytic functions. SUM OVER, for example, could be done as follows:

```sql
SELECT amount, 
    @sum := @sum + amount as sum 
FROM tbl
JOIN (SELECT @sum := 0) s
```

If you want to `PARTITION BY`, it's possible but just a bit more complicated. Basically, you add another `@variable` to watch the account (or whatever you want to partition by), order by account (or your variable), and then reset the `@sum` when the account changes. As follows:

```sql
SELECT account, 
    amount, 
    (case when @account != account then @sum := amount else @sum := @sum + amount end) as sum,
    (case when @account != account then @account := account else @account end) as _
FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY account)
JOIN (SELECT @sum := 0) s
JOIN (SELECT @account := '') a
```

You'll note two major changes that had to be done to accomplish the partition effect:

1. The main table (`tbl`) is encased in a sub select with an `ORDER BY` clause. This is necessary because when MySQL goes to do the `@account` variable testing the values need to already be ordered. If this didn't happen, you'd get incorrect sum values as well as account values.
2. There is an 'extra' column aliased `as _`. You can ignore this column when using results, but the order of the `@account` check and change needs to be after the `@sum` check and change.

   *Also with this, you could choose to reorder your columns if you didn't mind account being last. This is done by taking out the first `account` column since it duplicates with the last `_` column and then obviously renamed the aliased `_` to `account`.*

**Resources:**

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2563940/263175

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. I don't understand *why* it works, it's like magic lol.

Answer (score 0):

Although MySQL doesn't support analytic functions, [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) does. It's a drop-in replacement for MySQL and is created by the original developers of MySQL.

Comment: This answer is outdated: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Answer (score -5):

There is a commercial product for SQL Server that provides in-database analytic functions and it can be connected to an oracle or MySQL database via 'linked servers'/odbc - here is an article describing it:
http://westclintech.com/Blog/tabid/132/EntryId/88/Using-XLeratorDB-with-MySQL-and-other-RDBMS-s.aspx

This requires having a Windows o/s and SQL Server 2005 or later (which the Express version is free)