# I want to partition my table by the last name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to count and then partition my table by count over the C.LastName. I am just learning SQL and am not completely certain how the COUNT(...) line works in the program.

**Is this the correct way to count and partition the table on the LastName?**

For some reason this line of code in the SQL just seems to be a difficult beast to see how it completely works.

```
 select C.*,
        COUNT(*) over (partition by c.LastName) as '--Count--'
 from Customer C;
```

Table:

```
PrimaryKey  FirstName   LastName    MiddleName  PhoneNumber Address1    Address2    City    State   Zipcode
1   Test1                   LTest1                  MTest1                  5555555555      555 Governors                                       5555 Governors Avenue                               Pierre      TT          99999
2   Test2                   LTest2                  MTest2                  4444441234      444 Governors Street                                4444 Governors Blvd                                 Bill        PP          44444
3   Test3                   LTest3                  MTest3                  3333331234      333 Governors Street                                3333 Governors Street                               Pop         RR          33333
4   Test1                   LTest1                  MTest9                  7777777777      77 Governors Avenue                                 7 Governors Street                                  Yet         UU          22222
10  FirstName               LastNme                 MiddleName              8888888889      321 H Street                                        4321 U Street                                       TownUSA     VB          77777
11  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
13  NULL    A                       LTest                   NULL    HTest                                               NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
14  Test14                  LTest14                 MTest14                 1231231234      123 VVV                                             Billings                                            Billings    NULL    NULL
15  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
16  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
17  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
19  NULL    test                    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
20  NULL    NULL    NULL    1               123 ave                                             123 ave                                             NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Customer Table:

```
1   Test1                   LTest1                  MTest1                  5555555555      555 Governors                                       5555 Governors Avenue                               Pierre      TT          99999
2   Test2                   LTest2                  MTest2                  4444441234      444 Governors Street                                4444 Governors Blvd                                 Bill        PP          44444
3   Test3                   LTest3                  MTest3                  3333331234      333 Governors Street                                3333 Governors Street                               Pop         RR          33333
4   Test1                   LTest1                  MTest9                  7777777777      77 Governors Avenue                                 7 Governors Street                                  Yet         UU          22222
10  FirstName               LastNme                 MiddleName              8888888889      321 H Street                                        4321 U Street                                       TownUSA     VB          77777
11  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
12  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
13  NULL    A                       LTest                   NULL    HTest                                               NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
14  Test14                  LTest14                 MTest14                 1231231234      123 VVV                                             Billings                                            Billings    NULL    NULL
15  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
16  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
17  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
18  NULL    A                       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
19  NULL    test                    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
20  NULL    NULL    NULL    1               123 ave                                             123 ave   

                                        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

New Query:

```
SELECT C.*,
        A.B as "--Count--"
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT lastname,
         count(*) as B
  FROM customer
  GROUP BY lastname
) A
ON c.lastname = A.lastname;
```

Thank you below for showing me this example. Is the count(*) as B (I changed some of the variables just so that i could see that you could. A and B would not be good variable names to use.

Does the count(*) as B refer to the lastname in that select statement. This is the only statment that I am not really certain about.

Comment: What is your question?  You seem to be on the right track syntactically.

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Sever Management Studio

Comment: My question is why does the SQL statement not "compile" and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, COUNT(*) is not a supported analytic function. You can use the following query to get the same result:

```
SELECT 
    C.*,
    counts_lastname.cnt_lastname as "--Count--"
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT 
  lastname,
  count(*) as cnt_lastname
  FROM customer
  GROUP BY lastname
) counts_lastname
ON c.lastname = counts_lastname.lastname;
```

**References**:

[Analytic functions: SUM, AVG, ROW_NUMBER on EXPLAIN EXTENDED blog](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/08/analytic-functions-sum-avg-row_number/)

[A related question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806528/does-mysql-have-the-equivalent-of-oracles-analytic-functions)

Comment: COUNT(*) over (partition by c.LastName) as '--Count--' will not work then in SQL Server.

Comment: It does work in SQL Server. Please see this fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3aada/6 What error / output do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is correct, if you want to count people with the same last name. Those windowed functions can seem a bit daunting at first, but just play around with it, and look at your results and you should be fine. The fact that you post the question suggests you get a different result then expected, is that right?

Edit:
I jumped to conclusions and assumed sqlserver...