# MySQL 'partition by' clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting error in the partition clause. Please help me. The error is

```
 Select Model_Name,  
   Case Model_Subtype   
        When 'Weight' then 'Static'  
        When 'Linked Account' then 'Dynamic'  
        When 'Flexible' then 'Dynamic'  
       Else 'Not Defined'  
  End as Model_Type, Security_Name, Market_Value,Weight,  
  Case When Weight = 0 And Market_Value= 0 Then 0  
     When Weight  = 0 Then Cast(Market_Value/ nullif(SUM(market_Value)   
           OVER (Partition by Model_Name),0) AS Decimal (10,4))  
      When Weight !=0 Then Weight/100   
    Else Weight End as Target_Weight,  
         vehicle.Vehicle_Name  
    from   
  OFF_PRODUCT_MODEL model    
 Join OFF_PRODUCT_MODEL_TARGET target on target.Model_Id = model.Model_Id  
  Join OFF_PRODUCT_SECURITIES Sec on sec.Security_Id = target.Security_Id   
  left outer Join Offer_Back_End.tblStrategies Strategy on    Strategy.Vestmark_Sleeve_Code = model.Model_Name   
   left outer join Offer_Back_End.tblVehicles vehicle On vehicle.Vehicle_Id = strategy.Vehicle_ID
 Where (Strategy.Active_Strategy is null or Strategy.Active_Strategy = 1)
```

> Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '(Partition by Model_Name),0) AS Decimal (10,4))
>                     When Weight !=0 Then Weight/' at line 11

Comment: mysql doesn't support partitioning like that, and we are not a code translation service.

Comment: MySQL does not support the `OVER()` clause.

Comment: I don't think the question is a duplicate because the OP is asking for the *correct* syntax to perform this operation.

Comment: For those coming to this question now, [MySQL added `OVER()` window function with the 8.0 release](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-2-introducing-window-functions/).

Answer (score 3):

Umm, `OVER (Partition by Model_Name)` is analytical function which `MySQL` unfortunately doesn't support and don't have them and so you are getting the said error.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Thank you for your quick reply. Can you please tell me how do I convert Over(Partition by Model_Name ) clause in MySQL? I appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support `OVER()` clause. In general Window Functions are not part of MySQL.

You can however emulate it - please refer to the following answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20432371/900564