# How can I combine 2 SQL queries and retrieve a cumulative count?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve the number of visits and number of conversions each day for a particular A/B test combination. Each combination represents a different variation of an A/B test. Here I'm using just `'1'` and `'2'` to represent the variations, but technically there could be more variations.

I've written the following 2 queries, which work independently. Is it possible to combine these or write a single query that retrieves the data I want?

visits query:

```
SELECT DATE(visit.created), visit.combination, COUNT(visit.id) 
FROM visit 
WHERE visit.user_id = 6
AND visit.experiment_id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(visit.created), visit.combination
```

visits result:

[image]

conversions query:

```
SELECT DATE(conversion.created), conversion.combination, COUNT(conversion.id) 
FROM conversion 
WHERE conversion.user_id = 6
AND conversion.experiment_id = 1
AND conversion.goal_id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(conversion.created), conversion.combination
```

conversions result:

[image: conversions result]

Also it would be great if I could get retrieve a running total (cumulative) count, like below, see the last 2 columns. I've grouped the the table below by combination so the cumulative counts are easier to understand:

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| DATE(created) | combination | COUNT(conversion.id) | COUNT(visit.id) | cumulative_c | cumulative_v |
+---------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| 2015-11-17    | 1           |                    1 |               3 |            1 |            3 |
| 2015-11-18    | 1           |                    7 |               4 |            8 |            7 |
| 2015-11-19    | 1           |                    3 |               8 |           11 |           15 |
| 2015-11-17    | 2           |                    4 |               1 |            4 |            1 |
| 2015-11-18    | 2           |                    2 |               6 |            6 |            7 |
| 2015-11-19    | 2           |                    9 |               6 |           15 |           13 |
+---------------+-------------+----------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

The database schema:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining is quite simple: add 0-value columns, do `UNION_ALL`, then group again and sum.

```
SELECT dt, combination, SUM(v_count) as v_count, SUM(c_count) as c_count
FROM 
(
SELECT DATE(visit.created) as dt, visit.combination as combination, COUNT(visit.id) as v_count, 0 as c_count
FROM visit 
WHERE visit.user_id = 6
AND visit.experiment_id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(visit.created), visit.combination

UNION ALL

SELECT DATE(conversion.created) as dt, conversion.combination as combination, 0 as v_count, COUNT(conversion.id) as c_count
FROM conversion 
WHERE conversion.user_id = 6
AND conversion.experiment_id = 1
AND conversion.goal_id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(conversion.created), conversion.combination
) as t
GROUP BY dt, combination
```

Now, for running total. In more advanced DBMS this is called "window" or "analytic" functions. For example, in Oracle you can do this:

```
SELECT dt, combination, SUM(v_count) OVER (PARTITION BY combination ORDER BY dt) as v_cumulative
```

for the above query, and it would give you just what you want. However, MySQL doesn't have such functions. There are ways around, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806528/does-mysql-have-the-equivalent-of-oracles-analytic-functions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql) for example, but they are quite tricky.

Comment: Many thanks Timekiller :) this works and I'm doing the running totals in PHP. I tried but it doesn't appear trivial to do the running totals for each combination in MySQL, but thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help.

```
SELECT DATE(v.created), v.combination ,DATE(c.created), c.combination, COUNT(v.id), COUNT(c.id) FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN conversion c ON u.id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN visit v ON u.id = v.user_id
WHERE c.id = 6 AND v.experiment_id = 1 AND c.goal_id = 1
GROUP BY DATE(v.created), v.combination, DATE(c.created), c.combination
```

Comment: Please an an explanation to your answer.