# Mysql Sum daily totals into weekly totals for given date range

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently my db table has dailTotal values for every single day, I need to get these grouped into weekly totals.

Is it possible to add the daily totals up into weekly totals and display a row each weekly total between the given date range.

Im not quite sure where to start with this one. My current query to get is by day is:

```
SELECT dailyTotal
FROM   energyUsage
WHERE  meterIdentifier = '1300011505120'
      AND startTime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND startTime <= '2017-12-31 00:00:00';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weeks can be a bit ambiguous.  One handy definition is the built-in definition.  So, you can do what you want using `yearweek()` function:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(startTime) as yyyyww
     , SUM(dailyTotal)
FROM energyUsage
WHERE meterIdentifier = '1300011505120' AND
      startTime >= '2017-01-01' AND
      startTime <= '2017-12-31'
GROUP BY yyyyww
ORDER BY yyyyww;
```

You can check out the `mode` argument to control whether weeks start on Sunday or Monday and when the first week of the year is.  There is no mode that says:  "the first week of the year starts on Jan 1st", although you could put in logic for that purpose.

Note:  If `startTime` has a time component, I am guessing you want:

```
WHERE meterIdentifier = '1300011505120' AND
      startTime >= '2017-01-01' AND
      startTime < '2018-01-01'  -- note the inequality
```

Comment: If there is no rule for the year to start on Jan 1st what is it using in your query? As that is what I want

Comment: @user794846 . . . Read about the `mode` argument . . . https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT SUM(dailyTotal) AS weeklyTotal
FROM   energyUsage
WHERE  meterIdentifier = '1300011505120'
      AND startTime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND startTime <= '2017-12-31 00:00:00'
GROUP BY YEAR(startTime),WEEK(startTime);
```

Comment: This one doesnt seem to work:  Unknown column 'weeklyTotal' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0):

You could use an aggregate function:

```
SELECT dailyTotal,
       sum(dailyTotal) over (partition by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM StartTime)) as MonTotal
FROM   energyUsage
WHERE  meterIdentifier = '1300011505120'
      AND startTime >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'
      AND startTime <= '2017-12-31 00:00:00';
```

I am assuming a lot of things here but you get the idea.

1- The version of MySQL supports aggregated functions

2- Your field is of date type

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by EXTRACT(MONTH FROM StartTime)) as MonTotal
FROM   energyUsage
WHER' at line 2

Comment: what version of mysql allow over - partition?

Comment: $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.50-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: But you can reproduce it in MySQL. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806528/does-mysql-have-the-equivalent-of-oracles-analytic-functions