# MySQL query to return total Profit/Loss for a list of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table with 4 columns as follows.

```
TransactionID | Item | Amount | Date
------------------------------------
              |      |        |
              |      |        |
```

I have a lot of entries and what I want to be able to do is create a query that returns a list of the total Profit/Loss at each point in time?

Imagine I had the following transactions:

```
 Bought item for 5
 Sold item for 15
 Bought item for 5
 Sold item for 15
```

So I would want it to return something like this.

```
Profit/Loss | Date
------------------
-5          | 20-10-12
10          | 21-10-12
5           | 22-10-12
20          | 23-10-12
```

Is this possible with a MySQL query?

Comment: The solutions returns the SUM for each day but I want to know the total profit and loss on a certain. So basically I want to be able to tell how much money I've made overall at a certain point in time. So like I want to be able to see for example, on 01-08-12 the business had made a profit of €40.

Comment: updated my answer accordingly to your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Date` is stored as you show on the expected result this should work:

```
SELECT
   SUM(Amount) AS "Profit/Loss",
   Date
FROM your_table
GROUP BY(Date)
```

Otherwise id `Date` is of type `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` you could do something like this:

```
SELECT
   SUM(Amount) AS "Profit/Loss",
   DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%m-%y') AS Date
FROM your_table
GROUP BY(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%m-%y'))
```

references:

- [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

**EDIT (after OP's comment)**

to achieve the comulative SUM [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql) is a good hint:

```
SET @csum := 0;
SELECT
   (@csum := @csum + x.ProfitLoss) as ProfitLoss,
   x.Date
FROM
(
   SELECT
      SUM(Amount) AS ProfitLoss,
      DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%m-%y') AS Date
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY(DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%d-%m-%y'))
) x
order by x.Date;
```

essentialy you store the current sum into a variable (@csum) and for each row of the grouped transactions you increase it by the daily balance

Comment: I should think a column called `Profit/Loss` won't work in MySQL? `:)`

Comment: No worries. Tbh I'd probably avoid the forward slash altogether, but +1 anyway.

Comment: It is just to adhere to what @PriestVallon asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS ProfitOrLoss FROM TableName GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM TableName GROUP BY Date
```