# How to find the SUM of the Calculated Percentage Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Column which calculates the Percentage , like this

```
Convert(decimal(5,2),(PatCount*100)/@PatientCount) as Per
```

Now i want the Total Sum of the above calculated Percentage. So i tried doing this,

```
,SUM(Convert(decimal(5,2),(PatCount*100)/@PatientCount)) as pa
```

But i am not geting the Desired Result . For ex

```
Per %    Total %
6.00     6.00
7.00     7.00
85.00    85.00
```

I want the total Col to print as 98%.  Please can Somebody help me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

[**SQL FIDDLE Example**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad966/6)

```
select
    cast(PatCount * 100 / @PatientCount as decimal(5,2)) as Per,
    sum(cast(PatCount * 100 / @PatientCount as decimal(5,2))) over() as Total
from Patients as P
```

Comment: + 1 for over().  You beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

For the sum to work you will need a GROUPBY, then the sum is over the group.

Simplest is to do this in a separate query. There may be a way to do this with a sub-query or you could look into a cumulative sum: [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You have some options but using a `CROSS APPLY` should have pretty good performance characteristics.

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT SUM(CONVERT(decimal(5,2),(PatCount*100)/@PatientCount)) as Per
  FROM   YourTable
)
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(5,2),(PatCount*100)/@PatientCount) as Per
       , q.Per
FROM   YourTable
       CROSS APPLY q
```

or perhaps even better (to read)

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT CONVERT(decimal(5,2),(PatCount*100)/@PatientCount) as Per
  FROM   YourTable
)
SELECT q.Per, qtot.PerTot
FROM   q CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(Per) as PerTot FROM q) qtot
```