# How to transpose rows into columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have been working on how to transpose or pivot this table but after working for so many hours I am still stuck on this, can you please help me?

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
     `Time` datetime, 
     `IN` int, 
     `OUT` int
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (`Time`, `IN`, `OUT`)
VALUES ('2017-04-05 15:53:00', 40, '35'),
       ('2017-04-05 15:24:00', 40, '35'),
       ('2017-04-05 15:23:00', 40, '35'),
       ('2017-04-05 14:22:00', 42, '40'),
       ('2017-04-05 14:21:00', 42, '40'),
       ('2017-04-05 14:20:00', 42, '40'),
       ('2017-04-05 13:19:00', 33, '30'),
       ('2017-04-05 13:18:00', 33, '30'),
       ('2017-04-05 13:17:00', 33, '30'),
       ('2017-04-05 13:16:00', 33, '30'),
       ('2017-04-05 13:15:00', 33, '30'),
       ('2017-04-05 12:14:00', 29, '25'),
       ('2017-04-05 12:13:00', 29, '25'),
       ('2017-04-05 12:12:00', 29, '25'),
       ('2017-04-05 12:11:00', 29, '25'),
       ('2017-04-05 11:14:00', 35, '33'),
       ('2017-04-05 11:13:00', 35, '33'),
       ('2017-04-05 11:12:00', 35, '33'),
       ('2017-04-05 11:11:00', 35, '33');
```

I want my output to be something similar to this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn9DN.png)

The value in 'IN' column is always the same for that particular hour even entered several time, so I just need 1 value to be in my table same as with the value in 'OUT' column

The `Accum` is the accumulated sum for each hour, just make it optional if it is even possible.

I am doing the first part which is to transpose the 2 columns with this query

```
SELECT 
    'IN' AS A, [2017-04-05 15:53:00], [2017-04-05 14:22:00],,,,
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         [Time], [in], [out] 
     FROM 
         Table1) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
    (MAX([IN])
        FOR [time] IN ([2017-04-05 15:53:00], [2017-04-05 14:22:00],,,,)) AS PivotTable;
```

Comment: Your data is only in a same day or in many days

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
select [Type], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15]
from
(
  Select [Time], [Type], value
  from (
    select t2.*, sum([OUT]) over (order by [TIME]) as ACCUM
    from (Select Distinct DATEPART(HOUR, Time) as [Time], [IN], [OUT] from table1) t2
    ) A
  unpivot
  (
    value for [TYPE] in ([IN],[OUT],[ACCUM])
  ) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  sum(value)
  for [Time] in ([11], [12], [13], [14], [15])
) piv
```

Get more details from here to make it dynamic, 
[Simple way to transpose columns and rows in Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372276/simple-way-to-transpose-columns-and-rows-in-sql) 
[Accumulate a summarized column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862432/accumulate-a-summarized-column)

Comment: Perfect!!Thanks  a lot @Jigar 

Comment: Hi @jigar sorry but I need additional help here... as I found out that value on the OUT column sometimes changes and so what I want now is to get the latest value based on  time.  Also I want to have a query to show the Accum value based on a specified time.

Comment: For latest OUT value based on time, you can replace below source table query `Select Distinct DATEPART(HOUR, Time) as [Time], [IN], [OUT] from table1`. All ACCUM values are based on the time (11,12,13,14 and 15) I guess.