# Totals in a Table with Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am pulling some data from MySQL with PHP. I have added a ORDER by ID ASC clause to the query and this gives me results in the desired order.The ID column is the incrementing ID in MySQL to ensure uniqueness. What I want to do is as follows:

```
  ID       Payment       Accumulated Totals
  1        £200          £200
  2        £325          £525
  5        £205          £730
  7        £100          £830
```

As I am still a newbie, I am wondering how to implement the Accumulated totals column as shown above. I am thinking there should be some formula to work out accumulated totals in each row. I have failed to work out something though I am battling with this problem right now and will post code once I come up with something whether or not it works just to show my efforts.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I amy not have been clear, and sorry about that. What I send to mysql is only the payment and not the totals. As a payment is made, a user submits it via a form ending up with a table like:

Comment: I may not have been clear, and sorry about that. What I send to mysql is only the payment and not the totals. As a payment is made, a user submits it via a form ending up with a table in mysql with columns id payment only. Then the table above is what a user sees when viewing the records. So i hope to get the table above by using PHP after querying the data from MySQL. I ma seeing joints in answers (thanks for all the help) just that i only have one table in mysql.

Comment: @Bululu. The Joins you see are done between the same table (see my sqlfiddle examples). What don't you like about the approaches there?

Comment: I think it's clear what you're doing. The duplicate question I linked to shows how to calculate running totals, isn't that what you want?

Comment: @Filipe Silva, thanks for the explanation. It's not a matter of liking rather it's not knowing. I am not yet into joints so I have always thought joints are only used between 2 tables. I will try these answers and see what works.

Comment: @Bululu. You can use JOIN's (without the t.lol) in the same table the same way you would do with a second table. In this case to get the sum of all payments related to the id's smaller than the one in the "first" table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.Payment, SUM(t2.Payment) as Accumulated_Totals
from table t1
inner join table t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
group by t1.id, t1.Payment
order by t1.id
```

Comment: Note that this is pretty inefficient if the table is large, because it performs a huge cross-product.

Answer (score 0):

You can check various implementations of cumulative sum in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563918/1385896).

About your data, if you have the £ symbols inside your values, the sum will return 0. You will have to do something like :

```
REPLACE(Payment, '£', '') for it to be perceived as a summable value.
```

Here's a <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fffc/12)</kbd> showing how it can work for the two approaches mentioned in the previous answers.