# MySQL Select Multiple Columns And a SUM column

Tags: mysql

Lets says I got a table like this -

```
 id  |  name  |  salary
 01  |  ABCD  |  1000
 02  |  EFGH  |  2000    
 03  |  IJKL  |  3000
```

Now is it possible to get result set like this?

```
id  |  name  |  salary | SUM
01  |  ABCD  |  1000   | 6000
02  |  EFGH  |  2000
03  |  IJKL  |  3000
```

I tried `SELECT id, name, salary, SUM(salary) FROM table` but it just gives me one row. Is there any way to get all the rows with an extra column ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id, name, salary, SUM(salary) AS sum FROM table
```

EDIT: Think i misunderstood. Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT id, name, salary (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM table) AS sum FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  id,
  name,
  salary,
  (SELECT SUM(salary) FROM table)
FROM
  table
```