# Insert cummulative sum in mysql table using php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

listed with numerical values in my table, i'm trying to insert cummulative values through php to mysql table.
so that i can fetch them easily using select query for later uses.

I'm trying to figure out a php script which can insert values into this table (dmatrix), tried mysql variables but failed to send them/ insert into mysql table
Expected output:

```
id | datac |Cummulative   
1  | 200   | 200    
2  | 300   | 500  
3  | 400   | 900  
4  | 500   | 1400
```

Thanks in advance. please help me out friends

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: You can accomplish this with a query without saving the data in a column.  [This question's answers (your question is also a duplicate)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2563940/1004027) provide a good method to calculate it on the fly.   Let the DB do its job, instead of bogging it down with manually aggregated data that can get stale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions:

- I will assume you are using a [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) object to communicate with your MySQL database from your PHP script.
- I will assume that the `id` column in the `dmatrix` table is [auto-incrementing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

With those assumptions, the code will look like this:

```
<?php

$datac = $_POST['datac'];

$sql = '
    INSERT INTO dmatrix (datac, Cummulative)
    SELECT :datac1, :datac2 + IFNULL(SUM(datac), 0)
    FROM dmatrix
';

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':datac1', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':datac2', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I think if you think of `$values` in the above code as the `datac` input from a HTML form, the above code should work. Nevertheless, if you could you share the HTML code that takes inputs for 'datac', that might make things clearer.

Comment: hi shaunak i'm positng my html code php script should fetch the datac and perform cummulative function and it must insert into my table dmatrix CODE :-> <form name="myForm" action="allocatedb.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Input Data:</legend>
Area<input type="text" name="Aname"> &nbsp;pincode:<input type="text" name="pincode">
Agency:<input type="text" name="Agency"> >
Data count<input type="text" name="datac">
<input type="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>

Comment: hi shaunak i have got a error of using $dbh later i have solved it but again i'm hit with this ERROR :-> Call to a member function bindValue() on a non-object

Comment: when user enters a value in one text field(html) using this value php code must insert cummulative values into the cummulative coloumn which is shown in figure. thanks for your patience shaunak