# sql query : sum of all rows and display in column

Tags: sql-server

Here is My query :

```
SELECT Name,
       Quantity,
       Price,
       (Quantity*Price)[Total Price] 
  FROM Menu,
       Items_per_Table,
       [735294] 
 WHERE Menu.Item_id = Items_per_Table.Item_id 
       AND [735294].OrderNo = Items_per_Table.OrderNo 
       AND Bill_Generated = 'True'
```

It returns  :

```
Name                  Quantity   Price   Total Price
Aerated Drinks             1     30.00   30.00
Fresh Lime Soda/Water      3     60.00   180.00
```

Here I want the sum of total prices like this : 30+180 = 210 in another column.
How can I perform that ?

It Should Return :

```
Name                  Quantity   Price   Total Price    All Over Price
Aerated Drinks             1     30.00   30.00          30
Fresh Lime Soda/Water      3     60.00   180.00         210
```

Comment: So _all_  rows should have the total price as an extra column?

Comment: yes..
Let Me Show You.

Comment: You're using `SQL Server` syntax but the query is tagged `MySQL`. Which is it?

Comment: Person contacted with MySql may also be able to know this.
Why don't i give a chance to answer them

Comment: A good answer is _very_ different for SQL Server and MySQL, so you should change the tags to clarify what you want. You want the answer for SQL Server then. Which version? 2012?

Comment: A summing window over rows makes only sense, if the result set is sorted. For an answer to your question, see then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql

Comment: By the way, it's crucial which SQL software you are using, as there are notable differences between them.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012, this should do what you need;

```
SELECT Name,
       Quantity,
       Price,
       (Quantity*Price) [Total Price],
       SUM(Quantity*Price) OVER (ORDER BY menu.item_id) [All Over Price] 
  FROM Menu,
       Items_per_Table,
       [735294] 
 WHERE Menu.Item_id = Items_per_Table.Item_id 
       AND [735294].OrderNo = Items_per_Table.OrderNo 
       AND Bill_Generated = 'True'
ORDER BY menu.item_id
```

`SUM(...) OVER (ORDER BY...)` does the running sum in the order you give it. Since you have no order in your question, I arbitrarily chose menu.item_id to order by.

EDIT: Forgot to add the [SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/75dd9/2).

Answer (score 0):

Try using **Common Table Expressions**,(If you are using SQL < SQl 2012)

```
;with cteabc
as (
SELECT Name,
       Quantity,
       Price,
       (Quantity*Price)[Total Price] 
  FROM Menu,
       Items_per_Table,
       [735294] 
 WHERE Menu.Item_id = Items_per_Table.Item_id 
       AND [735294].OrderNo = Items_per_Table.OrderNo 
       AND Bill_Generated = 'True'
    )
select
    t1.Name,
    t1.Quantity,
    t1.Price,
    rt.runningTotal
from cteabc t1
 cross apply (select sum([Total Price]) as runningTotal
                from cteabc t2
                where  t2.rn<= t1.rn
            ) as rt
order by t1.Name
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/24e6d/1)**