# Mysql cumulative sum, with reset condition, group by period

Tags: mysql, grouping, cumulative-sum

I have a table with each row holding fields named id (key), date, sign, value.

Sign = 0 is a reset condition. It will be used to set initial cumulative value

Sign = +1 is an add condition. It will sum value to cumulative total.

Sign = -1 is a subtraction, and as you'll guess, it will decrease cumulative total.

Order is important, so they must be evalued with 0, 1, -1 ordering.

Let's say I'd want to obtain cumulative sum of the value.

```
SELECT my_date, my_sign, my_value, @cum AS cum_before,
(@cum := IF( my_sign !=0, @cum + my_sign * my_value, my_value ) ) AS cum_after
FROM my_table, (SELECT @cum :=0) as t WHERE my_date LIKE '2016-05-%'
ORDER BY my_date, my_sign + ( my_sign =0 ) *2 DESC;
```

Will correctly display:

```
my_date     my_sign  my_value cum_before    cum_after
2016-05-02        0  10000.00          0    10000.00
2016-05-02        1   1860.00      10000    11860.00
2016-05-02       -1   1860.00      11860    10000.00
2016-05-03        1   1780.00      10000    11780.00
2016-05-06        1   4625.00      11780    16405.00
2016-05-09        1  14200.00      16405    30605.00
```

Now I'd like to group it by week (or month), and having cum_before set to initial value before processing the rows in the group (which incidentally should be the cum_after of the previous group), and cum_after as the cumulative value after processing the rows in the group.
Things gets complicated as previous state variable @cum seems to be initialized with the first value of the group set.

I'm creating a temporary table to keep the correct ordering, as GROUP seems not to obey any ORDER BY clause (i'm guessing it's taking rows as they appears in the DB).

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _t_ SELECT id FROM my_table
ORDER BY my_date, my_sign + ( my_sign =0 ) *2 DESC ;
```

I'm using assign in place (@cum:=value), inside the SUM function, to change @cum accordingly when grouping, and multiply it by 0 not to interfere with real sum, which will sum sign*value in normal case, and will subtract @cum and add value field, when reset condition is found.

```
SELECT min( my_date ) AS MinDate, max( my_date ) AS MaxDate,
@cum AS cum_before, SUM( 
  0 * ( @cum := IF( my_sign !=0, my_sign * my_value, my_value ) ) + 
  IF( my_sign !=0, my_sign * my_value, - @cum + my_value ) 
) AS cum_after
FROM my_table as F, _t_, (SELECT @cum :=0) AS t
WHERE _t_.id = F.id AND my_date LIKE '2016-05-%'
GROUP BY date_format( my_date, "%y%U" );
```

will give the following:

```
MinDate     MaxDate     cum_before cum_after
2016-05-02  2016-05-06       10000  16405.00
2016-05-09  2016-05-09       14200  14200.00
```

which is wrong, because what I expect to obtain is:

```
MinDate     MaxDate     cum_before cum_after
2016-05-02  2016-05-06           0  16405.00
2016-05-09  2016-05-09       16405  30605.00
```

Basically it appears to assign @cum the first row in the set, instead of keeping previous variable value.

How can I obtain the correct grouping, if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Adapting a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25062874/mysql-cannot-cumulatively-sum-count?rq=1) by [Haleemur Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2570261/haleemur-ali)
it appears it cannot be done in a single step, as cumulative variable is reset after each group.
So a possible solution is the following:

```
SELECT MinDate, MaxDate, @cum as cum_before, (@cum:=@cum+tmp_cum) as cum_after
FROM ( SELECT min( my_date ) AS MinDate, max( my_date ) AS MaxDate,
SUM( 
  0 * ( @tmp := IF( my_sign !=0, my_sign * my_value, my_value ) ) + 
  IF( my_sign !=0, my_sign * my_value, - @tmp + my_value ) 
) AS tmp_cum
FROM my_table as F, _t_, (SELECT @tmp :=0) AS t
WHERE _t_.id = F.id AND my_date LIKE '2016-05-%'
GROUP BY date_format( my_date, "%y%U" ) ) as SUBQ, (SELECT @cum:=0) as tmp_var;
```

Don't know about performance, or if this can be optimized.