# Adding first two rows result as a second row then addition of first three rows result as a third row and so on

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in sql serevr,which has one column and its storing integer values.

Ex : ColumnData

---

```
   100

   150

   20

   25

   300
```

Now by using this data i want the result as shown below.

columndata                                                             NewColumn

---

```
   100        100

   150        250

   20         270

   25         295

   300        595
```

so in the output  newcolumn is added by the logic i.e first row data as firstrow,then first two rows addition result as appears in second row,then first three rows addition result as appears in third row like so on...

could any one please provide me the query how to get my result.

Thanks In Advance,

Phani Kumar.

Comment: `mysql <> sqlserver`, please tag properly.

Comment: This is called a "running total". I'm sure you can find out how to do it by googling that phrase.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a column that you can order the data by then you can compute a running total by either using a windowed aggregate function (this works in SQL Server 2012+) or a self join (which works in any version). If you don't have any column to order by then it can't be done in a deterministic way at all.

```
-- sample table:
create table t (id int identity(1,1), ColumnData int)
insert t values (100),(150),(20),(25),(300)

-- query 1 using windowed aggregate
select ColumnData, sum(ColumnData) over (order by id) as  NewColumn
from t order by id

-- query 2 using self-join    
select t1.ColumnData, sum(t2.ColumnData) as  NewColumn
from t t1
join t t2 on t2.id <= t1.id
group by t1.id, t1.ColumnData
order by t1.id
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3b9eb/2)

Comment: I've never seen `sum(<field>) over(order by <otherfield>)` without a `range` or `rows` expression, like `sum(<field>) over(order by <otherfield> rows unbounded preceding)`.  Is there a difference?  They appear to have different execution plans.

Comment: @BaconBits The window frame is optional. The documentation says: "If ROWS/RANGE is not specified but ORDER BY is specified, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used as default for window frame."

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PL SQL to to do this.
Alter the table to have a new field `id` to to sort and `value2` having final result.

```
DECLARE
 l_last_sum       INTEGER := 0;

 CURSOR test_cur
 IS
      SELECT id,value
        FROM test
    ORDER BY id ASC;

 l_test   test_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
 OPEN test_cur;

 LOOP
    FETCH test_cur INTO l_test;
    EXIT WHEN test_cur%NOTFOUND;

    l_last_sum:=l_last_sum+l_test.value;
    update test set value2=l_last_sum where id=l_test.id;

 END LOOP;

 CLOSE test_cur;
END; 



  SQL> select * from test;                                                                                

    ID      VALUE     VALUE2                                                                        
 ---------- ---------- ----------                                                                        
     1        100        100                                                                        
     2         25        125                                                                        
     3         40        165
```

Comment: The question is about MS SQL Server which doesn't support PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

with sal as(
select a.empid,salry,row_number() over(order by empid) rn from empmaster a)
select a.empid,a.salry,b.salry,a.salry+b.salry 
from sal a
left outer join sal b on a.rn = b.rn-1