# MySql - count from beginning until each day

Tags: php, mysql, count

Let's say I have the following table (keep in mind that this table will have 10000+ rows):

```
id    total           date
1       5        2015-05-16
2       8        2015-05-17
3       4        2015-05-18
4       9        2015-05-19
5       3        2015-05-20
```

I want the query to give the following result:

```
1
date => 2015-05-16
total => 5

2
date => 2015-05-17
total => 13

3
date => 2015-05-18
total => 17

4
date => 2015-05-19
total => 26

5
date => 2015-05-20
total -> 29
```

I can't think of any query that would do this right now, that's why I am not providing any code that I have tried.

Any thoughts? I am not sure if this is possible only with mysql, maybe I have to use and php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using user defined variable in mysql and then get the running total as

```
select
id,
total,
date
date from
(
 select
 id,
 @tot:= @tot+total as total,
 date from my_table,(select @tot:=0)x
 order by date
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
SELECT 
     a.id, 
     a.date, 
    (SELECT SUM(b.total) FROM your_table WHERE b.date <= a.date) as new_total       
FROM your_table a, your_table b 
ORDER BY a.date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
select id, (select sum(total) from table a where a.date <= b.date)  from table b
```