# how to change Mysql variable inside query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table with two columns namely cumulative_sum and absolute.
But I only have cumulative value. I would like to calculate absolute value.

Cumulative Value

12

19

32

41

Expected Absolute Value

12

7

13

9

I have try a query like this. I just need to update @absvalue to cum every time query update.

```
set @absvalue := 0;
update pdb_tint_result set abs = (cum - @absvalue)
where user_id='P6'
order by date;
```

Can you please guide me?

I saw calculating cumulative sum [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)
I try to make it work for calculation Abs value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something automatically with a changing variable I will recommend using triggers. To use triggers in your case

```
"CREATE TRIGGER update_abs 
 BEFORE UPDATE ON pdb_tint_result
 FOR EACH ROW SET abs = cum - New.absvalue;"
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: Can u please explain more? how do i use this

Comment: @Chit, when you create a trigger, its something like an automated action which will always happen `BEFORE` or `AFTER` an event. In your case you need it to happen `BEFORE` the `UPDATE` event. So using the trigger above will always subtract the `new absvalue` from the `cum` before updating the `abs`.

Comment: Mind you, triggers are not the SQL, so after specifying the trigger you then run your sql's

Comment: @Soe, here the best way to say thank you is to mark your question as solved by checking the answer which helped you most

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SET @prev_cum:=0;
UPDATE test_point_sum 
   SET absolute_value = (cumulative_sum - @prev_cum),
       cumulative_sum = @prev_cum:=cumulative_sum 
   ORDER BY 
      ID ASC;
```

Pick your table and column names. tested and verified. see if this helps

Comment: it got right only for the first two rows. other value is wrong.

Comment: Edited my post now; earlier It was updating for iterative absolute_value. nevertheless, updated query would help.