# MySQL calculation of cumulative sum with a reset condition

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to capture a cummulative sum with a reset condition in mySQL?  The use case for this is a simple cash register table

```
id    transactionType      value  CurrentBalance
1      purchase             10        10
2      sale                -10        0
3      RESET                20        20
4      purchase             10        30
5      sale                -10        20
6      sale                 10        30
7      sale                -20       10
```

The answer from here is a good starting point but I don't see how to extend it:
[Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

```
SELECT t.id,
         t.count,
         @running_total := @running_total + t.value AS CurrentBalance
    FROM TABLE t
    JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
ORDER BY t.id
```

NOTE:  basically the idea is to reset the cumulative sum each time a reset is hit.  Ideally I am trying to have an on update/insert trigger which will update the entire CurrentBalance column taking into account RESETs.  This is a small table so I don't mind updating the whole table in exchange for something simple.

Comment: Just wrap the `@running_total + t.value` in an `IF(transactionType='RESET',0,[yourmath]) AS CurrentBalance`

Comment: A lot of people would advise against storing calculated values inside the database like that.

Comment: Agree!  in fact I decided not to  store the data,  I will just create a View with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All this requires is some simple conditional logic:

```
SELECT t.id, t.count,
       @running_total := if(transactionType = 'RESET', t.value,
                            @running_total + t.value
                           ) as CurrentBalance
FROM TABLE t JOIN
     (SELECT @running_total := 0) params
ORDER BY t.id;
```