# Mysql Biased/Weighted Random Selection

Tags: mysql, random

I'm using the following query to select a random campaign:

```
SELECT * from (  
SELECT campaign_id
FROM campaigns
WHERE campaign_approved = 1
) T ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1
```

However, I'd like to select campaigns, still randomly, but with odds of being selected in proportion to their `campaign_balance`.

> So for example, if one campaign has a campaign_balance of 50 and the
>   other has a campaign_balance of 1.....the first one should have 50 /
>   51 chance of being selected.

How do I do a random selection that is biased like this?

Comment: you need to assign this campaign_balance in a new cumulative column, then ramdomly select between 1 and max cumulative value and find it.

Comment: I'm still learning mysql, this makes no sense to me :)

Comment: look at this for cumulative column or running total http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql

Comment: Create a new table with a structure like this: campaing_id, campaign_balance, cumulative_chance.  Does it make sense to you?

Comment: campaign_balance already exists in the table

Comment: ok, great, you can create a new table or add a new column, cumulative_chance. This column will be calculated as mentioned in previous link.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to run a selection efficiently. Updating a table and then selecting is two queries?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100692/discussion-between-horaciux-and-amy-neville).