# Calculate cumulative sum of unsold products

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I am trying to show total of unsold products using mysql and I want to calculate it using FIFO manner

For example

Purchase

```
stockdate   stockquantity 
24/02          100
25/02          200
```

Sales

```
salesdate   salesquantity
25/02          50
```

Output

Items unsold = 250

But Items should get sold from date 24/02

Following is the procedure what I tried so far

```
BEGIN

DECLARE item_sold INT;
DECLARE total_quantity INT;

SELECT item_sold= (SELECT sum(salesquantity) from Sales);

SELECT total_quantity = (SELECT stockquantity , case when stockquantity < item_sold then item_sold = item_sold-stockquantity when stockquantity > item_sold then stockquantity= stockquantity-item_sold AND item_sold = 0 AND +total_quantity when stockquantity = item_sold then item_sold = 0 end as total_quantity from Purchase order by stockdate);

select item_sold;
select total_quantity;
END
```

Can any one please suggest me what I am doing wrong? or is this correct way of doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you @Shadow but I have a condition to subtract also

Comment: So what? You include it with a negative sign in the addition process. Sg like `@csum := @csum + stockquantity - salesquantity`.