# Difference between two values used to find running total

Tags: mysql

I have one table called "GOLDSTOCKTABLE"

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+  
!ID ! GRAM !  GRAMTOBANK ! LOCKERBALANCE  !
+----------+-------------+----------------+ 
!1  ! 10   !    9        !                !
!2  ! 15   !    10       !                ! 
!3  ! 8    !    8        !                ! 
!4  ! 45   !    40       !                !
+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

On each entry of record ,the difference between GRAM and GRAMTOBANK stored with the cumulative sum as in LOCKERBALANCE,The resultant table look like

```
+----------+-------------+----------------+  
!ID ! GRAM !  GRAMTOBANK ! LOCKERBALANCE  !
+----------+-------------+----------------+ 
!1  ! 10   !    9        !    1           !
!2  ! 15   !    10       !    6           ! 
!3  ! 8    !    8        !    6           ! 
!4  ! 45   !    40       !    11          !
+----------+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @TheoTonge Here the difference between GRAM and GRAMTOBANK is used for the calculation of running total

Comment: OK yes they are slightly different - have added an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to store cumulative sum:

```
select ID, GRAM, GRAMTOBANK
       , @lb := @lb + (GRAM - GRAMTOBANK) as LOCKERBALANCE  
from
    (select @lb := 0) x,
    (select ID, GRAM, GRAMTOBANK
     from GOLDSTOCKTABLE
     order by ID) y
```

Comment: @Mc Nets Can we use the exact query with the php script,Does variables works perfectly?

Comment: But it should works as some other script. @AjithVManali

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using variables - note you must run the first query to set the variable to 0 before you then run the main query.

```
SET @LOCKERBALANCE=0;

SELECT 
  GOLDSTOCKTABLE.*, 
  (@LOCKERBALANCE := @LOCKERBALANCE + (GRAM-GRAMTOBANK)) as LOCKERBALANCE
FROM GOLDSTOCKTABLE
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Can you paste the CREATE TABLE statement for GOLDSTOCKTABLE and confirm your mysql version?

Comment: Actually this is a table with 26 columns,For understand easily i shrink the table with 4 columns,In which version the code works?

Comment: The number of columns should not change the result, I have just tested with an additional 50 columns on a test table and it still works. The main reason for seeing the CREATE TABLE statement would be to see the exact data types used for each column.

Comment: 1 GLID PrimaryIndex int(5)                                                               
2 GRAMTOBANK int(5)                                                                        3 GRAMTOBANK int(5)   
4      LOCKERBALANCE int(10)

Comment: I am a bit confused why this would not work - are you running directly on the mysql client?

Comment: on XAMP's   PhpMyadmin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136045/discussion-between-theo-tonge-and-ajith-v-manali).