# Incremental Count(*) using YEARWEEK

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of data stored in a table, each row ends with a `ts` column, type `TIMESTAMP`.

I want to get incremental counts up until a point, so for instance I have the following query:

`SELECT YEARWEEK(ts), DATE(ts), COUNT(*) FROM`order`WHERE DATE(ts) >= '01/12/13' GROUP BY YEARWEEK(ts)`

Which produces something like:

```
201346  20/11/2013  59
201347  24/11/2013  44
201348  01/12/2013  21
```

However I need a column that adds up the COUNTS *up until* that point, so I'd need something like:

```
201346  20/11/2013  59 59
201347  24/11/2013  44 103
201348  01/12/2013  21 124
```

How can I achieve this with mysql??  It's for a line graph, so I need to show that the numbers go up each week and I can't do that with the current SQL statement.

Comment: Can you give a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET @SUM:=0;
SELECT YEARWEEK(ts), DATE(ts), COUNT(*),(@SUM := @SUM+COUNT(*))  as CSUM
FROM orders WHERE DATE(ts) >= '01/12/13' GROUP BY YEARWEEK(ts)
```

courtesy [this answer from Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @Chud37 This is not the right answer. If you carefully see the answer linked in this, you'll see why it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user variables to get the running count:

```
set @total := 0

select YEARWEEK(ts),
    date(ts),
    COUNT(*),
    @total := @total + COUNT(*) as running_count
FROM order
WHERE date(ts) >= '01/12/13'
group by YEARWEEK(ts)
order by YEARWEEK(ts);
```