# Mysql aggregated sum line by line

Tags: mysql, sql

Table t1:

```
date       profit
2011-01-01  100
2011-01-02  -50
2011-01-03   25
```

I'd like to get an output like:

```
date       aggregated profit
2011-01-01  100
2011-01-02   50
2011-01-03   75
```

Any suggestion for an efficient MySQL query?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a cumulative sum.  The most efficient method uses variables:

```
select t.*, (@sum := @sum + profit) as cumulative_profit
from (select t.*
      from t
      order by date
     ) t cross join
     (select @sum := 0) params;
```

Note that in earlier versions of MySQL, the subquery is not necessary.  Somewhere around 5.7, the subquery became needed for the variable to respect the ordering.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry that I have not found this nice discussion before bothering you:
[create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @VengaVenga . . . Unfortunately, the accepted answer to that question doesn't work in the most recent versions of MySQL because you need a subquery for the `join`.