# sum sequentially in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a query which would look like this..

```
|tipe of operation | UMT | Total |
__________________________________
|reach             | 1.5 |  1.5  | 
|reach             | 1.5 |  3    | 
|reach             | 1.5 |  4.5  | 
|take              | 1   |  5.5  | 
|take              | 2   |  7.5  |
```

(that the total field is added together according to the columns)*

I have tried in several ways and I can not achieve .....
    so far my most advanced query is this, which gives me the following result ...

```html
|tipe of operation | UMT | Total |
__________________________________
|reach             | 1.5 |  1.5  | 
|reach             | 1.5 |  1.5  | 
|reach             | 1.5 |  1.5  | 
|take              | 1   |  1    | 
|take              | 1   |  1    |
```

this is my query

```
select   tablamtmtipo as 'tipe of operation'
       , tablamtmdatos as 'UMT'
       , sum(tablamtmdatos) as Total 
from tablamtm 
WHERE tablamtmoperacion = 'operación 1' 
group by idtablamtm
```

I only have one table with these fields

```
1- idtablamtm
2- tablamtmoperacion
3- tablamtmtype
4- tablamtmdatos
```

Comment: So, what you want from us? Please give more information about your table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: What column defines the order?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Is there any PK defined for your table ?

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
select   tablamtmtipo as 'tipe of operation'
       , tablamtmdatos as 'UMT'
       , @total:=@total+ tablamtmdatos as Total 
from tablamtm 
WHERE tablamtmoperacion = 'operación 1' 
group by idtablamtm
```

Comment: I am trying to make your query and the result gives me null in this field  "@total: = @ total + tablamtmdatos as Total"

Comment: before query select 
use this query
SET @total = 0;