# Mysql update using query or sp

Tags: mysql

I have a tables in a MySQL database like this:

Intially it will be like this. 
i want to update the table using query.

inital Weekly =5, and update it in accural, 
next i want to update the 5+6=11 in accural
next 11+7 =18 in accural column

how to do that?

## Leave:

```
userid     | Weekly |Accural |
-----------+--------+---------+
1          | 5      |        |
2          | 5      |        |
3          | 5      |        |
```

OUTPUT:

```
userid     | Weekly |Accural  |
-----------+--------+---------+
1          | 5      |  5      |
2          | 6      |  11     |
3          | 7      |  18     |
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)