# MySQL update field until value is reached

Tags: mysql

I have an mysql table with file information with the following partially structure:

```
id  filename    size(mb)      status
1   one.pdf       100         active
2   two.pdf       200         active
3   three.pdf     50          active
4   four.pdf      120         active
```

Considering, for example, that I have a 300Mb limit, I want to update the status to inactive for the following rows after that value is reached. This would be the final result:

```
id  filename    size(mb)      status
1   one.pdf       100         active
2   two.pdf       200         active
3   three.pdf     50          inactive
4   four.pdf      120         inactive
```

Is there any way to do this with an mysql instruction to avoid performance issues by doing it programmatically?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql. It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: What if the limit was 290 or 310?

Comment: Yes it did! thank you!