# How to cummulative sum in MySql with grupBy and interval?

Tags: mysql

Table Sales

```
date        id_product  total sales
2018-10-01  1             40
2019-09-01  1             20
2019-11-01  1             5
2019-12-01  1             40
2020-01-01  1             10  
2020-02-01  1             15    
2020-03-01  1             20
2020-08-01  1             10
2021-01-01  1             5
2021-02-01  1             8
2021-04-01  1             12
```

Table Product

```
id      name
1       Book
2       Pen
```

How to query in MySql to get the number (serial/sequential number) and the total cumulative sales with an interval of 3 years to get results like this?

```
number name  date  sum_sales   cummulative_sales
1      Book  2018  40          40
2      Book  2019  65          105
3      Book  2020  55          160
4      Book  2021  25          145
```

Comment: share DB fiddle link for the same

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql ?

Comment: that question not use interval

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are running MySQL 8+, you may try using `SUM` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.name ORDER BY YEAR(s.date)) number,
    p.name,
    YEAR(s.date) AS date,
    SUM(s.total_sales) AS sum_sales,
    SUM(SUM(s.total_sales)) OVER (PARTITION BY p.name ORDER BY YEAR(s.date)) AS cummulative_sales
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN Product p
    ON p.id = s.id_product
GROUP BY
    p.name,
    YEAR(s.date)
ORDER BY
    p.name,
    YEAR(s.date);
```

Comment: the cumulative_sales value is incorrect. I want to make interval in 3 years in cumulative_sales. Example the value for 2020 is cumulative beetween 2018-2020 and the value for 2021 is cymulative beetween 2019-2021

Answer (score -1):

Using MySQL 5.7, this will give you a sum and a cumulative sum of sales in a window of 3 years.

```
SELECT (@row = @row + 1) AS number, name, YEAR(date) AS date, 
SUM(total_sales) as sum_sales,
iF(
    @window > 0, 
    @cummulative_sales := @cummulative_sales + SUM(total_sales), 
    @cummulative_sales := SUM(total_sales)
) AS cummulative_sales,
@window := @window + 1,
@window := @window % 3

FROM Sales
JOIN Product ON Sales.id_product = Product.id,
(
    SELECT @row := 0, @cummulative_sales := 0, @window := 0
) as a
GROUP BY name, YEAR(date);
```

Comment: Please test code before posting, and note that this kind of method is essentially deprecated

Comment: which kind of method is deprecated @Strawberry

Comment: @variables - and in any event, this isn't (wasn't) the right way to use them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24673769/5460261 @variables is being used and it's working as well, how is it not the right way to use them. If it's not the right way to use them then what is the right way

Comment: No, back in 2014 that usage was also incorrect (although OMG Ponies has a correct example at that same link)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2564009/5460261 in the first answer OMG Ponies mentioned using the cross join which is the same that I have written. And OMG Ponies has written the same answer. using JOIN or cross JOIN has the same complexity in this scenario

Comment: @aRvi I believe your approach is deprecated as of MySQL 8+.  Not sure if it would be considered valid before that.

Comment: You haven't tested your code. But anyway, it's beside the point. When used correctly, this method was valid 5 years ago. It's not valid today.

Comment: What is valid today then?

Comment: can you share any valid resource that it is not valid?

Comment: See TB's answer. And https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html , which points out that defining user variables in this way is maintained for backwards compatibility only.

Comment: Ok, I have changed to Mysql 5.7 in the answer. I have not worked on MySQL 8, so I don't have any idea about new features in MySQL 8. Will this query will give an error in MySQL 8?

Comment: @aRvi It _might_ work on MySQL 8, but the point is that it might break on future versions of MySQL.  Also, even if it works, it won't port to any other SQL database (save perhaps an early version of MariaDB).