# Add previous value of one column to present value of another column and get result column

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

[image]

I want to replace `null` values in P by logic

```
present value of column P =  present value of column S + previous value of column P.
```

Expected output:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What `MySQL` version are you using ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha 8.0.25

Comment: Does the table has an id autoincrement ?

Comment: No Basha. It does not have

Comment: I think the first column to be populated should be `P` then you can update `R`

Comment: Yes basha. That is the requirement

Comment: What sorting expression provides shown rows ordering? how to determine what row is "next row"?

Comment: @Akina I have edited question. It is more clear now

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have edited question. Could you please look into this?

Comment: Your edition changes nothing. *how to determine what row is "next row"?* - your edition does not answer.

Comment: @AshokAnumula I think you need to add first an id autoincrement to determine the row sort as @Akina mentioned. Use:  `ALTER TABLE your_table ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST ;`

Comment: @ErgestBasha Added autoincrement Id in first column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a Cumulative Sum Column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql)

Comment: @Progman My question is diferent from what you suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this by using variables in mysql

```
SELECT 
    pur.Id, pur.s,
    (@b := @b + pur.s) - 10 AS p
FROM
    (SELECT @b := 0.0) AS dummy 
  CROSS JOIN
    purchase AS pur
ORDER BY
    Id ;
```