# Progressive count using a query?

Tags: sql, mysql, stored-procedures, count

I use this query to

```
SELECT userId, submDate, COUNT(submId) AS nSubms
FROM submissions
GROUP BY userId, submDate
ORDER BY userId, submDate
```

obtain the total number of submissions per user per date.
However I need to have the *progressive count* for every user so I can see how their submissions accumulate over time.

Is this possible to implement in a query ?

EDIT: The obtained table looks like this :

```
  userId submDate nSubms
  1       2-Feb    1
  1       4-Feb    7
  2       1-Jan    4
  2       2-Jan    2
  2       18-Jan   1
```

I want to produce this :

```
  userId submDate nSubms  progressive
  1       2-Feb    1           1
  1       4-Feb    7           8
  2       1-Jan    4           4
  2       2-Jan    2           6
  2       18-Jan   1           7
```

EDIT 2 : Sorry for not mentioning it earlier, I am not allowed to use :

- Stored procedure calls
- Update/Delete/Insert/Create queries
- Unions
- DISTINCT keyword

  as I am using a tool that doesn't allow those.

Comment: do you need 1 cumulative number per day, per hour and for comparisons between which time spans?

Comment: Have a look at the **UPDATE** section in my answer to this similar question: [Optimal query to fetch a cumulative sum in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144766/optimal-query-to-fetch-a-cumulative-sum-in-mysql/3144820#3144820)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a self-join to grab all the rows of the same table with a date before the current row:

```
SELECT s0.userId, s0.submDate, COUNT(s0.submId) AS nSubms, COUNT (s1.submId) AS progressive
FROM submissions AS s0
JOIN submissions AS s1 ON s1.userId=s0.userId AND s1.submDate<=s0.submDate
GROUP BY s0.userId, s0.submDate
ORDER BY s0.userId, s0.submDate
```

This is going to force the database to do  a load of pointless work counting all the same rows again and again though. It would be better to just add up the `nSubms` as you go down in whatever script is calling the query, or in an SQL variable, if that's available in your environment.

Comment: I'm afraid the code does not work as expected... I guess the general concept is correct though.

Comment: also this will cause absolutely horrible performance problems. Don't do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

The Best solution for this is to do it at the client.
It's the right tool for the job. Databases are not suited for this kind of task

Comment: Well, some databases support window/analytic functions to do this very simply. But not SQL Server.

Comment: true. but IMO this is still a client side responsibility. that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select S.userId, S.submDate, Count(*) As nSubms
    , (Select Count(*)
        From submissions As S1
        Where S1.userid = S.userId
            And S1.submDate <= S.submDate) As TotalSubms
From submissions As S
Group By S.userid, S.submDate
Order By S.userid, S.submDate
```

Comment: @Wartin - I've corrected my query and tested on my system. Should work fine now.

Comment: Thomas, there is no such field as "S.nSubms". "nSubms" is a calculated field in the query I used.

Comment: @Wartin - Simple fix. Just replace Sum with Count(*). I've adjusted my query to accomodate. On my tests, this produced the correct output. This does rely on the fact that submDate is a datetime column.

Comment: That's genial solution!! I adapted this query to another example and it is possible to create a counter with a progressive number for each duplicate field! Wow, congratulations!