# Weighted random pick from array in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

I have a model in Rails from which I want to pick a random entry.
So far I've done it with a named scope like this:

```
named_scope :random,  lambda { { :order=>'RAND()', :limit => 1  } }
```

But now I've added an integer field 'weight' to the model representing the probability with which each row should be picked.

How can I now do a weighted random pick?

I've found and tried out two methods on snippets.dzone.com that extended the Array class and add a weighted random function, but both didn't work or pick random items for me.

I'm using REE 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.

Comment: It might be good to add what DB are you using. It's not hard to do in Ruby but doing it in the DB might be a lot more efficient.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention I was using mysql. But I was so focused on solving that in ruby that I didn't even consider to solve it on the query level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I understand this totally wrong, but couldn't you just use the column "weight" as a factor to the random number? (Depending on the Db, some precautions would be necessary to prevent the product from overflowing.)

```
named_scope :random,  lambda { { :order=>'RAND()*weight', :limit => 1  } }
```

Comment: You are right about weight being the factor to the random number. This was really far more simple than I initially thought! Thank you!

Comment: this won't work as expected. Suppose a table with 999 records, all weights are 1 except for one that's 2. You'd expect that the special record is selected 1/500 of times (as its weight is 2 and the total weight is 1000), but in fact it's selected half of the times (every time its rand() evaluates to more than 1). Moreover, it's executing 1000 times the rand() function, even if you wnant just one record. You'd better get the total in one query, use ruby to select a point in the weight interval, and then select just one record based on that number.

Answer (score 0):

In one query you should:

- calculate the total weight
- multiply by a random factor, giving a weight threshold
- scan again through the table summing, until the weight threshold is reached.

In SQL it would be sompething like this (not tried for real)

```
SELECT SUM(weight) FROM table INTO @totalwt;
@lim := FLOOR(RAND() * @totalwt);
SELECT id, weight, @total := @total + weight AS cumulativeWeight
     FROM table WHERE cumulativeWeight < @lim, (SELECT @total:=0) AS t;
```

Inspired by [Optimal query to fetch a cumulative sum in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3144766/optimal-query-to-fetch-a-cumulative-sum-in-mysql)