# MySQL Running Total with COUNT

Tags: mysql

I'm aware of the `set @running_sum=0;` `@running_sum:=@running_sum + ...` method, however, it does not seem to be working in my case.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(date), COUNT(*) AS count 
   FROM table1
   WHERE date > '2011-09-29' AND applicationid = '123'
   GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

The result gives me unique dates, with the count of occurrences of application 123.

I want to keep a running total of the `count`, to see the accumulated growth.

Right now I'm doing this in PHP, but I want to switch it all to MySQL.

Using the method from the first line of this post simply duplicates the count, instead of accumulating it.

What am I missing?

P.S. The set is very small, only about 100 entries.

Edit: you're right ypercube:

Here's the version with running_sum:

```
SET @running_sum=0;
SELECT date, @running_sum:=@running_sum + COUNT(*) AS total FROM table1
   WHERE date > '2011-09-29' AND applicationid = '123'
   GROUP BY date ORDER BY date
```

count column ends up being the same as if I just printed COUNT(*)

Comment: Is `date` of `date` datatype?

Comment: Can we see the `@running_sum` code that isn't working for you?  Perhaps that's what needs to be fixed in this case...

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is probably useless here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Updated Answer

The OP asked for a single-query approach, so as not to have to SET a user variable separately from using the variable to compute the running total:

```
SELECT d.date,
       @running_sum:=@running_sum + d.count AS running
  FROM (  SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS `count`
            FROM table1
           WHERE date > '2011-09-29' AND applicationid = '123'
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date ) d
  JOIN (SELECT @running_sum := 0 AS dummy) dummy;
```

"Inline initialization" of user variables is useful for simulating other analytic functions, too.  Indeed I learned this technique from answers [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3333697/132382).

### Original Answer

You need to introduce an enclosing query to tabulate the `@running_sum` over your COUNT(*)ed records:

```
SET @running_sum=0;
SELECT d.date,
       @running_sum:=@running_sum + d.count AS running
  FROM (  SELECT date, COUNT(*) AS `count`
            FROM table1
           WHERE date > '2011-09-29' AND applicationid = '123'
        GROUP BY date
        ORDER BY date ) d;
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290936/132382).

Comment: Thank you! One small fix: COUNT(*) AS count. Otherwise, d.count fails.

Comment: @djdy: It's better not use names like `date` or `count` for columns or tables, in any case. `DATE()` is a function and `COUNT(*)` is an aggregate function.

Comment: @pilcrow they aren't really named that in the real query, I used those just for the sake of example here. Is there any way to set a MySQL variable and do the select in 1 query? I am stuck with a setup that can't do multiqueries.

Comment: @djdy: yes, you can initialize the user variable in a derived table.  See my updated answer.

Comment: In your updated answer, I had to change `@accum` to `@running_sum`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this one actually works for me (lots of similar ones didn't really work correctly for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

SQL is notoriously poor at running totals.  As your result set is in order, you are *much* better advised to append a calculated running total column on the client side.  Nothing in SQL will be as performant as that.

Answer (score 1):

The Running total can be easily calculated using the lib_mysqludf_ta UDF library.

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_ta#readme