# Retrieve running-total record growth over time in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, cumulative-sum

I have a Drupal site which has a table that keeps track of users. What I want to do is graph membership growth over time. So I want to massage mysql into returning something like this:

```
date | # of users (total who have registered up to the given date)
1/1/2014 | 0
1/2/2014 | 2
1/3/2014 | 10
```

**Where '# of users' is the total number of users that have registered accounts up to the given date (running-total)--NOT the number of users who registered on that particular day** (which is trivial to retrieve).

Each row of my `{users}` table has a `uid` column, a `name` column, and a `created` (timestamp) column.

So a sample record from my `{users}` table would be:

```
name: John Smith
uid: 526
created: 1365844220
```

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: Query would be something like SUM(#ofusersColumn) with a date before clause of some sort

Comment: @JW I've updated my original post with a sample record. Basically, the only thing relevant is the `created` column.

Comment: @user466764 I want to retrieve a running-total count for a number of dates, though (something I can graph), not just the total number of users that have registered by one particular date. I want mysql to return something like: 
`1/1/2014 : 0 | 1/2/2014 : 2 | 1/3/2014 : 10`

Comment: Do you want a row returned for every day, regardless of whether any users registered on that day, or only on days when users registered? If you want rows for every day, do you have a date table already set up which holds a date for every day?

Comment: @MarkBannister Just days when users register is fine... not really an issue currently, since users register every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a solution that incorporates variables, based on a Stack Overflow answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359077/mysql-running-total-with-count). This solution appears to be a bit more flexible and efficient than other answers provided.

```
  SELECT u.date,
  @running_total := @running_total + u.count AS count
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(created), '%b %d %Y') AS date
    FROM {users}
    WHERE created >= :start_time AND created <= :end_time
    GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)), DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(created))
  ) u
  JOIN (
    SELECT @running_total := u2.starting_total
    FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(*) as starting_total
      FROM {users}
      WHERE created < :start_time
    ) u2
  ) initialize;
```

Note that the group by, date formatting, and range requirements are simply specifics of my particular project. **A more generic form of this solution (as per the original question) would be:**

```
  SELECT u.date,
  @running_total := @running_total + u.count AS count
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(created)) AS date
    FROM {users}
    GROUP BY date
  ) u
  JOIN (
    SELECT @running_total := 0
  ) initialize;
```

Comment: This was a serious lifesaver for me. For posterity: note that this method is also way faster than the accepted answer. One note: the counts are off for me if I don't provide a starttime (you can omit the endtime).

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
select u.created, count(*)
from (select distinct date(created) created from `users`) u
join `users` u2 on u.created >= date(u2.created)
group by u.created
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/172c9/1).

Comment: Thanks @Mark! This looks very promising... Unfortunately `created` is a unix timestamp rather than a datetime (sorry if I was not clear on that), but I'm guessing I can get this to work with a little fiddling using DATE(created)...

Comment: @JordanMagnuson: I've updated my query to truncate the date with `date(created)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark. Your solution did work for my stated use case. Unfortunately I had some issues with it in application, both in the efficiency realm (the query seemed very slow when working with tens of thousands of records), and when it came to implementing specific range and date formatting needs for my project (which I did not post in the original question). I posted my own answer with the code I ended up using, but thanks a lot for your solution.

Comment: @JordanMagnuson: I hadn't realised performance was going to be an issue when I suggested my answer - I had considered an answer that used variables, but this was simpler to code.

Comment: @Mark: There seems to be a bug, although I can't figure it out, please see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/b56bd/1  and the counts

Comment: I see, it yields total growth over time, I thought it was supposed to count entries per day

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the table structure so adjust the query to you needs

```
SELECT DATE(created), COUNT(*) AS Users FROM users GROUP BY DATE(created)
```

When you only want to show the dates having registerd users add

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0
```

At the and of the query

Comment: This will give me the number of users who registered on each date, but not the TOTAL number of users who have registered up to the given date... (see the bold sentence in my original post)