# Getting a running total of some DISTINCT records

Tags: mysql

I have a table that tracks our user logins. We have a dashboard for admins etc that shows a graph of the running total.

I do this with the following query ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951146/retrieve-running-total-record-growth-over-time-in-mysql)) :

```
SELECT t.date, @running_total := @running_total + t.count AS count
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count, DATE(datetime) AS date
    FROM user_login
    WHERE datetime >= '2013-05-01'
    GROUP BY date
) t
JOIN (
    SELECT @running_total := t2.starting_total
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) as starting_total
        FROM user_login
        WHERE datetime < '2013-05-01'
    ) t2
) initialize;
```

user_login has a datetime column and a user_id. However, now I've been asked to also show a running total of the unique user logins (e.g.: user 1 logged in twice on one day and user 2 once, that's 3 logins, but 2 "unique"). I tried doing this with:

```
SELECT t.date, @running_total := @running_total + t.count AS count
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count, DATE(datetime) AS date
    FROM user_login
    WHERE datetime >= '2013-05-01'
    GROUP BY date
) t
JOIN (
    SELECT @running_total := t2.starting_total
    FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as starting_total
        FROM user_login
        WHERE datetime < '2013-05-01'
    ) t2
) initialize;
```

but it's giving me incorrect results, I'm assuming because in `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS count, DATE(datetime) AS date` selecting count AND date is throwing it off.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need such a complex join to get the number of logins per day per user, using a count(*) and a GROUP BY will get the result quickly.

```
SELECT u.userid, count(*) logins_for_the_day, date(u.datetime) the_day
 FROM user_login u 
 WHERE datetime >= '2013-05-01'
 GROUP BY date(u.datetime)
 ORDER BY u.user_id, datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a running total, why don't you just do this?

```
SELEcT date, cnt
FROM (SELECT DATE(datetime) AS date, @running_total := @running_total + count(*) as cnt
      FROM user_login cross join
           (select @running_total := 0) const
      GROUP BY date
     ) ul
WHERE datetime >= '2013-05-01';
```

You can now modify this for unique logins per day:

```
SELEcT date, cnt, cntu
FROM (SELECT DATE(datetime) AS date, @tot := @tot + count(*) as cnt,
             @totu := @totu + count(distinct user_id) as cntu
      FROM user_login cross join
           (select @tot := 0, @totu := 0) const
      GROUP BY date
     ) ul
WHERE datetime >= '2013-05-01';
```

Note:  this gives the sum of the unique logins on each day (which is what your question appears to be asking).  I suspect you actually want the number of unique logins overall (not just within a day).  For this, you'll need an additional subquery, to calculate the uniques.  This comes by looking at the *first* day someone logs in:

```
SELEcT ul.date, ul.cnt, uld.cntu
FROM (SELECT DATE(datetime) AS date, @tot := @tot + count(*) as cnt
      FROM user_login cross join
           (select @tot := 0) const
      GROUP BY date
     ) ul left outer join
     (SELECT DATE(first_datetime) as date, @totu := @totu + count(*) as cntu
      FROM (select ul.user_id, min(datetime) as first_datetime
            from user_login
            group by ul.user_id
           ) ul cross join
           (select @totu := 0) const
     GROUP BY DATE(first_datetime)
    ) uld
    on uld.date = ul.date
WHERE datetime >= '2013-05-01';
```