# MySQL - How to query for an aggregate count value with a time interval

Tags: mysql, count, intervals

I am trying to write a single MySQL query which will tell me the total number of active users in the database in week-based intervals. The 2 returned values per row should be the date, and the total number of active users on that date. I was able to get this far:

```
SELECT from_days(to_days(cast(u.created as datetime)) - mod(to_days(cast(u.created as datetime)) - 1 - 1, 7)) AS date, COUNT(1) as count
FROM users u
WHERE u.active = 1
GROUP BY 1;
```

I believe this shows me the number of new active users in each given interval, but I can't figure out how to 'aggregate' those counts to show the total number of users increasing over each time interval. Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without an example of your output but I would start by making the whole thing a subquery and using an aggregate function or a calculation on top of it.

See this post:

[MySQL Running Total with COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359077/mysql-running-total-with-count)