# SQL calling all Fields

Tags: mysql

I have a question, I am trying to list all of the actors for each movie in my database. Right now I have this SQL

```
    SELECT title, count(1) COUNT, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
FROM film
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film.actor.film_id
INNER JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
GROUP BY title.
```

What I am trying to do is format my out put into a text file like this:

```
Title:Number of Actors in each film: Actor first name(1): Actor last name(2) : Actor first name(2): Actor last name(2) ... ect
```

But for example, in the first film there are ten actots for this film. How would I print out the first and last name of each actor for each movie.

Comment: Are you wanting to see the specific (#) of the actor in the movie?  based on what order? (the only way I know of doing this in mysql is with user variables. example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359077/mysql-running-total-with-count

Comment: Or perhaps you need to just simulate the`row_number() over partition by xxxx)` functionality: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you want aggregate and non-aggregate data.

One way to achieve this in MySQL you would have to get the count of actors in each film as a sub query and join back to the base set.

```
SELECT title, b.cnt COUNT, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
FROM film
INNER JOIN film_actor 
   ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN actor 
   ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT film_ID, count(1) as cnt 
            FROM film_actor 
            GROUP BY film_ID) B
 on film.film_ID =  B.Film_ID
```

in databases which support window functions you could use a `count(1) over (parttition by film.film_ID) as cnt`

It may also be able to be achieved by using a group by with rollup without using an added join; but this creates an additional row with the total.

```
SELECT title, count(1) COUNT, actor.first_name, actor.last_name
FROM film
INNER JOIN film_actor 
   ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
INNER JOIN actor 
   ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
 on film.film_ID =  B.Film_ID
GROUP BY title with rollup
```