# MYSQL Sub Select Not Working

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run two queries in one. When I run both queries seperatley, they work and provide me with the relevant information I want. When I try to combine them I seem to be going wrong somewhere. Is there something blatantly obvious that I am doing wrong?

```
 SELECT 
   pd.product_id, b.product_id, basket_qty, 
   product_name, product_price, product_image, 
   pd.category_id, basket_id
 (SELECT 
   pd.product_id, b.product_id, 
   basket_session_id, 
   SUM(product_price) AS subtotal 
  FROM 
   basket b, product pd 
  WHERE 
   basket_Session_id = '9htt961lpa1kqieogd5ig5ff93' AND 
   b.product_id = pd.product_id)
 FROM 
   basket b, product pd, department dep
 WHERE 
   basket_session_id = '9htt961lpa1kqieogd5ig5ff93' 
   AND b.product_id = pd.product_id 
   AND dep.department_id = pd.category_id
```

Table Structure -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `basket` (
  `basket_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `basket_qty` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `basket_session_id` char(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `basket_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`basket_id`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id`),
  KEY `basket_session_id` (`basket_session_id`)
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
  `product_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `department_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `product_description` text NOT NULL,
  `product_price` decimal(7,2) NOT NULL default '0.00',
  `product_qty` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `product_size` text NOT NULL,
  `product_image` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `product_date` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`product_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `product_name` (`product_name`),
  KEY `category_id` (`category_id`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `department` (
  `department_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `department_parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`department_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `department_parent_id` (`department_parent_id`)
)
```

I am trying to pull product information based on a "basket" session for an ecommerce application. As a basket can contain more than one product I want to return the SUM of total value from all products.

Comment: A semicolon is missing after first basket_id?

Comment: This simply is not valid Syntax. Giving us an idea wht you want to select from what table structure will help us find a solution for you

Comment: IT appears you're trying to get a subtotal for the results one way to achieve this is to use [with rollup](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?12,106959,106959), another way would be to use variables to keep a [running total](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql), and a final way would be to use a correlated subquery

Comment: Can you narrow down the issue? Remove all those fields that I'm sure aren't necessary to ask the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This won't work as the sub-query is effectively a column returned in the overall query, however, your sub-query returns more than one column. You could remove the extra columns though and do this, which should work.

```
 SELECT pd.product_id, b.product_id, basket_qty
      , product_name, product_price, product_image
      , pd.category_id, basket_id
        -- moved from sub-query
      , basket_session_id 
      , ( SELECT SUM(product_price) 
            FROM basket b, product pd 
           WHERE basket_Session_id = '9htt961lpa1kqieogd5ig5ff93' 
             AND b.product_id = pd.product_id ) AS subtotal
  FROM basket b, product pd, department dep
 WHERE basket_session_id = '9htt961lpa1kqieogd5ig5ff93' 
   AND b.product_id = pd.product_id 
   AND dep.department_id = pd.category_id
```

Comment: Subqueries are pretty much an anti-pattern. And you aren't using a `GROUP BY` with your `SUM()`.

Comment: That has done it! I didn't realize that was the problem. It makes sense now as I think I was returning about 4 columns for the sub... Thanks

Comment: @Jules I don't need a group by as I've not select any other columns. Secondly, it's a bit rude to down-vote an alternative answer to one's own.

Comment: @Jules: why are subqueries an *anti-pattern*? They are the corner stone of the SQL language.

Comment: @Ben Pretty sure you had more columns selected before. Anyway this subquery is still an anti-pattern. The query is clearly not optimized and is a disgrace for any SQL developer. Even if this query does what is requested by Rory, it's not contributing to the performance or to his knowledge.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Read this query and question yourself if this could not be optimized by not making use of the subquery.

Comment: @Jules, you can see the answer hasn't been edited. I can **prove** with trace files in my DB that sub-queries **can** be faster and better for the DB in every respect; I spent an hour on one query 2 weeks ago as, in that instance, it made no sense to me. Making a sweeping statement does not make it correct.

Comment: @Jules: I agree that in this case a sub-query is not needed. But stating that sub-queries in general are an anti-pattern (and thus bad) is simply wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you add a comma right before your subselect..

```
SELECT 
   pd.product_id, b.product_id, basket_qty, 
   product_name, product_price, product_image, 
   pd.category_id, basket_id,  
 (SELECT ...
```

Other than that your query doesn't look valid to me. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I am sure there are way better queries than the one you just wrote.

So I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve and I don't know how your database looks like but modify this query to fulfill your needs. It should be a good start for you:

```
SELECT pd.product_id, b.product_id, b.basket_qty,
       pd.product_name, pd.product_price, pd.product_image,
       pd.category_id, b.basket_id, b.basket_session_id, 
       SUM (pd.product_price) AS subtotal
FROM product pd
JOIN basket b ON b.product_id = pd.product_id
JOIN department dep ON dep.department_id = pd.category_id
WHERE b.basket_session_id = '9htt961lpa1kqieogd5ig5ff93'
GROUP BY product_id
```

Also notice that you use the `department` table but you never select any field from it or anything. So it seems to be useless here. I just added it in my query in case you want to improve it later on.