# Optimization of adding a cumulative (running total?) column?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am new to sql and this forum has been my lifeline till now. Thank you for creating and sharing on this great platform.

I am currently working on a large dataset and would appreciate some guidance.

The data table (existing_table) has 4 million rows and it looks like this:

```
id  date   sales_a   sales_b   sales_c   sales_d   sales_e
```

Please note that there are multiple rows with the same date.

What I want to do is to add 5 more columns in this table (`cumulative_sales_a`, `cumulative_sales_b`, etc.) which will have the cumulative sales figures for a, b, c, etc. till a particular date (this will be grouped by date). I used the following code to do this:

```
create table new_cumulative  
select t.id, t.date, t.sales_a, t.sales_b, t.sales_c, t.sales_d, t.sales_e,   
(select sum(x.sales_a) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_a,  
(select sum(x.sales_b) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_b,  
(select sum(x.sales_c) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_c,  
(select sum(x.sales_d) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_d,  
(select sum(x.sales_e) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_e  
from existing_table t  
group by t.id, t.date;
```

I had created an index on the column 'id' before running this query.

Though I got the desired output, this query took almost 11 hours to finish.

I was wondering if I am doing something wrong here and if there is a better (and faster) way of running such queries.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a running total in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @fthiella. I went through this post earlier. However, my data has multiple entries per date as well. Also, I have multiple ids, so I want a cumulative total per id per date. I hope that this is making sense.

Comment: i think that the link i gave you is a good starting point, but since you are also grouping, you probably have to use a subquery... if you don't get any other answer, later i'll have a look at this

Comment: If anyone looks at this post in future, I was able to get a much faster turn around time by creating indexes on all 7 columns in the table. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some queries are expensive by nature and take long time to execute. In this particular case you could avoid having 5 subqueries :

```
SELECT a.*, b.cumulative_sales_a, b.cumulative_sales_b, ...
FROM 
(
 select t.id, t.`date`, t.sales_a, t.sales_b, t.sales_c, t.sales_d, t.sales_e
 from existing_table t  
 GROUP BY t.id,t.`date`
)a
LEFT JOIN 
(
  select x.id, x.date, sum(x.sales_a) as  cumulative_sales_a,
  sum(x.sales_b) as cumulative_sales_b, ...
  FROM existing_table x 
  GROUP BY x.id, x.`date`
)b ON (b.id = a.id AND b.`date` <=a.`date`)
```

It's also expensive query, but it should have a better execution plan than your original. Also, I'm not sure if

```
select t.id, t.`date`, t.sales_a, t.sales_b, t.sales_c, t.sales_d, t.sales_e
 from existing_table t  
 GROUP BY t.id,t.`date`
```

gives you what you want - for instance, if you have 5 records with the same id and date, it will grab values of other fields (sales_a, sales_b, etc) from any of these 5 records...

Comment: Thanks @a1ex07. Let me try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

you may join all mini-select with sum in one query as

```
(select sum(x.sales_a) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_a,  
(select sum(x.sales_b) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as  cumulative_sales_b,  
(select sum(x.sales_c) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_c,  
(select sum(x.sales_d) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_d,  
(select sum(x.sales_e) from existing_table x where x.id = t.id and x.date <= t.date) as cumulative_sales_e
```

in

```
select sum(..),sum(..),sum(...),sum(..),sum(..)
from existing table x 
where x.id=t.id and x.date<=t.date
```

Comment: Thanks @Constantine Kuznetsov. Let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: @SunMun, I do not believe that will work as they are trying to get the daily summation and overall up to the given date all in a single row.

Comment: Also you may debug defferent variants by adding limit in fisrt(create SELECT select) query. also you may create index for fast executing where clause

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an excellent spot for MySQL variables querying.  In this case, I would pre-query all the aggregations by your expected "ID" and "Date" to remove the duplicates and have a single entry as a grand total for the one day.  Take this result and have it ordered by the ID and date to prepare for the next part joining to the "@sqlvariables" versions.

Now, just process them in order and keep accumulating for each ID until the new ID, then reset the counter back to zero, but keep adding the respective "Sales".  After each "record" is processed, set the @lastID to the ID just processed so it can be compared when processing the next row to identify if continuing on same person, or force reset back to zero.

To help optimize and ensure the inner "PreAgg"regate query ensure an index on (ID, Date).  Should be SUPER Fast for you.

```
SELECT
      PreAgg.ID,
      PreAgg.`Date`,
      PreAgg.SalesA,
      PreAgg.SalesB,
      PreAgg.SalesC,
      PreAgg.SalesD,
      PreAgg.SalesE,
      @CumulativeA := if( @lastID := PreAgg.ID, @CumulativeA, 0 ) + PreAgg.SalesA as CumulativeA,
      @CumulativeB := if( @lastID := PreAgg.ID, @CumulativeB, 0 ) + PreAgg.SalesB as CumulativeB,
      @CumulativeC := if( @lastID := PreAgg.ID, @CumulativeC, 0 ) + PreAgg.SalesC as CumulativeC,
      @CumulativeD := if( @lastID := PreAgg.ID, @CumulativeD, 0 ) + PreAgg.SalesD as CumulativeD,
      @CumulativeE := if( @lastID := PreAgg.ID, @CumulativeE, 0 ) + PreAgg.SalesE as CumulativeE,
      @lastID := PreAgg.ID as dummyPlaceholder
   from 
      ( select 
              t.id, 
              t.`date`, 
              SUM( t.sales_a ) SalesA, 
              SUM( t.sales_b ) SalesB, 
              SUM( t.sales_c ) SalesC,
              SUM( t.sales_d ) SalesD,
              SUM( t.sales_e ) SalesE
           from
              existing_Table t
           group by
              t.id,
              t.`date`
           order by
              t.id,
              t.`date` ) PreAgg,
      ( select 
              @lastID := 0,
              @CumulativeA := 0,
              @CumulativeB := 0,
              @CumulativeC := 0,
              @CumulativeD := 0,
              @CumulativeE := 0 ) sqlvars
```