# Merge values based on select in h2

Tags: sql, select, merge, h2

I want to `MERGE` values based on the value of a select from another table.  Something like this:

```
MERGE INTO table1 (column1) key(id) 
    values (select amount from table2 where id = id limit 1 + 
    select column1 from table1 where id = id - 1 limit 1) 
    where id > 0
```

I want this to happen for each row where id is greater than 0.  Additionally, I want the value of column1 in table1 to be the value of column1 in the previous row plus the value of column2 in table2.

I am using [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html).

Comment: Is this some kind of running total problem when you say "previous row plus..."? H2 supports [running totals using the MySQL syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql).

Comment: Yes, this helps me do what I want.  It doesn't set the values of a new table to the result but with this answer I don't need to.  Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasMueller, FYI ... Alison replied to your comment but you probably didn't get notified.