# Pass a Running Total query using CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, cumulative-sum

I am using CodeIgniter and trying run a query but it will not work. I believe that the error relates to the `SET @runtot:=0;` line.  Here is the code:

```
<?php 
$qryRunningTotalRFRs = $this->db->query("
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT
   q1.w,
   q1.c,
   (@runtot := @runtot + q1.c) AS rt
FROM
(SELECT week(IssuesFiledDate) AS w,
count(*) AS c
FROM tblappeals
WHERE tblappeals.Outcome = 'Upcoming' 
    AND tblappeals.`Year` = 2013  
    AND `IssuesFiledDate` >= '2013-03-31'
GROUP BY w
ORDER BY w ) 
AS q1
"); ?>
```

Can someone suggest a way to modify this so that I can pass this running sum query to MySQL?  Thanks.

Comment: @runtot is it your database field name??

Comment: No, @runtot is just an abbreviation for 'running total'.  I just realized that perhaps my answer below is not correct because I am not getting the results I expected.  The running total is not being calculated.  I guess I am back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

I read the following comment on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql) which said:

> Don't miss the SET statement at the top to initialize the running total variable first or you will just get a column of NULL values.

For this reason, I believed that the SET statement was required for my query to work correctly.  Problem was, the query would not run with the SET statement.  I deleted the SET statement, and now it works fine.  For whatever reason, I guess the SET statement is not required in this context.