# Select Statement with value of next row used in where clause in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

Is is possible to construct a `SELECT` statement that contains a `WHERE`
clause that uses the value from a column in the "next" row?

I have a date and time field date_entered.
ie. given a table with a field named "date_entered" with the
following values I want a SELECT statement that selects the rows
"`WHERE date_entered>='current_date' and date_entered<=[NEXT ROW]date_entered` "

I tried [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18273215/how-to-get-previous-record-value-from-mysql-query) but not found what I am looking at.

Comment: You are good for a self join.

Comment: can you please add some pseudo code for that @mika?

Comment: are your records ordered chronologically ?

Comment: No records can be in any order.@mika

Comment: What record is contained in the "next row" depends explicitly on how the data is sorted. It's not clear what you're asking here. An example of input and output would have been helpful. Maybe you just want to `ORDER BY date_entered DESC`

Comment: date is stored as 2014-04-09 06:09:16 format.and question is quite clear that I want value of next date in my where clause?@symcbean

Answer (score 1):

If your records are ordered chronologically, then you may get through with a query like this:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
    min(t2.date_entered) as next_row_date 
from mytable t1 
join mytable t2
/* ON nothing */
where t1.id < t2.id
and t1.date_entered > NOW()
group by t1.id
having t1.date_entered <= next_row_date
```

If you really need next row date... You will likely get a better result with a subquery. Something like

```
SELECT 
    t1.*,
from mytable t1 
where t1.date_entered > NOW()
and t1.date_entered < ( SELECT date_entered from mytable t2 where t2.id > t1.id limit 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but my records are not ordered chronologically.

Comment: t.id and t2.id are not auto increment value rather they are 36 key values.

Comment: So how do you know which record is "next" ? If you have a record with key A, what would be your query to find the following record ? This is what the subselect is doing.

Comment: Thanks @mika its helps me to some extent

Comment: @Naeem you are welcome. I am glad I could help. How did you solve your issue in the end ? Do you mind posting your solution ?