# MYSQL Row Count if criteria is met

Tags: mysql

Sorry but I am not sure how to phrase this question or if it is possible but basically I am using a select statement in which I would like to display a column showing a count of when a criteria is met. For example

```
SELECT pageID, isHome, if(ishome = 1, 'count?', 0) AS Passed
FROM pages
```

I would like the `passed` column to show a running count kind of like this

```
PageID | ishome | passed
10031  | 0      | 0
10032  | 1      | 1
10033  | 1      | 2
10034  | 1      | 3
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql

Comment: Can you post your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following (untested)

```
select a.pageid, a.ishome, sum(b.ishome) passed 
from 
pages a join pages b
on a.pageid>= b.pageid
group by a.pageid, a.ishome
order by a.pageid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT pageID, isHome,  count(*)  AS Passed 
    FROM pages
    where ishome = 1
    GROUP BY PageID
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a6bf/8)

if you want show all result then use this

```
 SELECT pageID, isHome,  if(ishome = 1, count(*), 0)  AS Passed 
 FROM pages
 group by pageID,ishome ;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a6bf/26)

Comment: Yeah- that's DEFINITELY not what was wanted ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this is want you want.

```
SELECT pageID, isHome, 
case when(ishome = 1)
  then count(*)
  else 0
end Passed FROM Table1
group by pageID;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19af03/11)

OR if you want the number of passed pages

```
SELECT isHome, 
case when(ishome = 1)
  then count(*)
  else 0
end Passed FROM Table1
group by isHome;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19af03/14)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT pageID, isHome,
CASE isHome 
  WHEN 1 THEN SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pages p 
              WHERE p.isHome = 1 AND p.pageID <= pageID 
  ELSE 0 
END as passed
FROM pages
ORDER BY pageID ASC
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  This looks good but I was hoping to show the value of the 'passed' column to show an incremental value.  For example, if I had 4 rows that matched isHome = 1, then each passed column in each row would not show 4 but would show 1,2,3,4.  Not sure if that makes any sense