# total and partial sums in one table mysql

Tags: mysql

I would like to join two tables in one. I first are totals sums and in secound is partial sums.

**result**

```
something | total | month
xxxx      |  100  |  20
yyyy      |  125  |  45
```

**data**

```
goods|price|month
xxx  |5    |2
xxx  |8    |2
yyy  |3    |3
```

Is possible use WHERE on one colomn?

Comment: You said two tables, but only posted one table and results.

Comment: Are these both input tables? If so, what should the results be? What is the relationship between the two tables that you want to join them on? What does `WHERE` have to do with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate a running total in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

Comment: what is total, and what is month?

Comment: I thought that i can have two separate table of results.
one from `SELECT count(price) FROM ... GROUP BY goods` and secound the same with `WHERE month=2` on end. But I'd like to make one query.