# Cumulative sum query on foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a query for cumulative sum in MYSQL. I have a foreign key in my table and I want to add their hours as a cumulative sum.

Table 1

```
id(not primary key)   Hours
1                       4
2                       4
1                       5
```

I have tried this query

```
select spent_hours := spent_hours + hours as spent 
from time 
join (select spent_hours := 0) s
```

I am getting this

```
id(not primary key)    hours    spent
1                       4        4
2                       4        8
1                       5        13
```

But I want this result:

```
id(not primary key)    Hours spent
1                       4    4
2                       4    4
1                       5    9
```

Comment: Okay. What have you tried?

Comment: select spent_hours := spent_hours + hours as spent from time join (select spent_hours := 0) s

Comment: Please add your query (using [edit]) to your question.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1290936/2055998) for correct syntax using MySQL variables.

Comment: Would it be OK to have `spend` field be the user cumulative and user not running cumulative? so `1-4-8` `2-4-4` `1-4-8`?

Comment: Also how hard set are you on the table structure? Would you be able to add an autoincrement field?

Comment: i have an autoincrement field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an autoincrement field (let's assume for this case its called record_id) you can use this little trick to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT Main.id, Main.spentHours,
(
    SELECT SUM(spentHours) 
    FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.id = Main.id
    AND Table1.record_id >= Main.record_id
) as totalSpentHours
FROM Table1 Main
ORDER BY Main.record_id ASC
```

This will fetch the id, current spent hours, along using a subselect, all hours from the current ID and above for that user.

Comment: Based on the expected result, OP wants **running total**.

Answer (score 0):

You need additional an variable to keep track of the cumulative sum within each id:

```
select t.id, t.hours,
       (@h := if(@i = id, @h + spent_hours,
                 if(@i := id, spent_hours, spent_hours)
                )
       ) as spent
from time cross join
     (select @h := 0, @i := 0) params
order by id, ??;
```

Note:  you need an additional column to specify the order for the cumulative sum (indicated by `??` in the `order by` clause.  Remember that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so you need a column to explicitly represent ordering.

Comment: I'm not convinced it's 'needed' (the variable, not the key) but it is a great solution.