# SQL Pivot sum with specific condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot in order to sum specific month as the total, below is my table and sql pivot:

```
CREATE TABLE yt
([Store] varchar(10), [Month] varchar(10), [xCount] int)
;

INSERT INTO yt
([Store], [Month], [xCount])
VALUES
('A', 'JAN', 1),
('A', 'FEB', 10),
('B', 'JAN', 2),
('B', 'FEB', 20),
('C', 'JAN', 3),
('C', 'FEB', 70),
('C', 'MAR', 110)    
;

    select *
    from 
    (
      select Store, Month, xCount
      from yt
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      sum(xcount)
      for Month in ([JAN], [FEB], [MAR])
    ) piv;

Store   JAN FEB MAR
A        1  10  NULL
B        2  20  NULL
C        3  70  110
```

The above result I am able to sum the value by the current month. Now I want to sum all the month when Store a, sum only FEB, and MAR in Store b, and Store c sum MAR, so I want my result as

```
Store   JAN FEB MAR
A        6  100 110
B        5  90  110
C        3  70  110
```

Can I do it in pivot? Or need to create a table to run sql again? 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For `Sql Server 2008` you need some self join and ordering to make a running sum. Here I take store as this ordering:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT * FROM @yt 
             PIVOT(SUM(xcount) FOR Month IN ([JAN], [FEB], [MAR])) piv)
SELECT  c1.Store ,
        SUM(c2.jan) AS jan ,
        SUM(c2.feb) AS feb ,
        SUM(c2.mar) AS mar
FROM    cte c1
        JOIN cte c2 ON c1.Store <= c2.Store
GROUP BY c1.Store
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is running total order by store desc
In SQL Server2005+, You can try this:

```
SELECT Store,
    SUM([JAN]) OVER(ORDER BY Store DESC) AS [JAN],
    SUM([FEB]) OVER(ORDER BY Store DESC) AS [FEB],
    SUM([MAR]) OVER(ORDER BY Store DESC) AS [MAR]
FROM (
SELECT *
    FROM
    (
      SELECT Store, Month, xCount
      FROM yt
    ) src
    PIVOT
    (
      SUM(xcount)
      for Month in ([JAN], [FEB], [MAR])
    ) piv
) AS A
ORDER BY Store
```

But in MySQL, you can reference [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I run my sql get error:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: Oh! My code's used SQL 2005+  (use Window function)

Comment: Oh, why your tag: sql-server? I mean, my code in SQL Server :)

Comment: sum with order by is available from `sql server 2012`

Comment: Thanks for your help @NguyễnHảiTriều Hải Triều

Comment: @Arzozeus - There is no MySQL 2008. Based on your code and error, you are using SQL Server 2008

Comment: @ughai: In first time, he put his tag: sql-server. Then, he fixed it.

Comment: use of `[` to surround a table name is not supported in MySQL which uses ticks (`)

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are using SQL SERVER 2012, you can use

SELECT STORE,
       SUM(JAN)
         OVER (
           ORDER BY RN DESC) JAN,
       SUM(FEB)
         OVER (
           ORDER BY RN DESC) FEB,
       SUM(MAR)
         OVER (
           ORDER BY RN DESC) MAR
FROM  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
                OVER (
                  ORDER BY STORE)RN,
              *
       FROM   (SELECT STORE,
                      MONTH,
                      XCOUNT
               FROM   #YT) SRC
              PIVOT ( SUM(XCOUNT)
                    FOR MONTH IN ([JAN],
                                  [FEB],
                                  [MAR]) ) PIV)A 
ORDER BY RN ASC
```

Comment: thanks for your help, if i run in 2008 will show error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'order'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near 'A'. it seems 2008 not support over method, i guess