# How to get count of employees with total employee with group by year

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my employee table

```
empid   name     Date_of_joining
  1      dilip       2010-01-30
  2      suresh      2001-03-01
  3      ramesh     2003-01-01
```

I want to get the number of employees with total employees group by employee date of joining

**expected output**

```
   year    new joining    total employees
   2001          10                10
   2002          12                22
   2003          15                27
```

**query**

```
 select YEAR(`DATE_OF_JOINING`) as 'year', COUNT(*) as 'count1',sum(count(*)) from employee 

 GROUP BY YEAR(`DATE_OF_JOINING`)
```

Comment: Since we don't know anything about your table(s) ... how can we help?

Comment: And the problem is ?.... ther query seems ok. what's the problem? error?

Comment: how to get that no total employees

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a running total in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3):

You need a running total using a user defined variable.

You need a derived table cause running totals don't work with group by statement

```
SET @SUM = 0;
SELECT
  YEAR,
  NoOfEmployee AS newJoining,
  (@SUM := @SUM + NoOfEmployee) AS totalJoining
FROM (
    SELECT
      YEAR(Date_of_joining) AS YEAR,
      COUNT(*) AS NoOfEmployee
    FROM
      employees
    GROUP BY
      YEAR(Date_of_joining)
  ) O
```

here a [sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f716/11)