# Delete some rows to bring each group total below the threshold

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-delete, delete-row

I have a `Ledger` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Ledger
 (
     PersonID int,
     Narration varchar(255),
     Payment int(255)
 ); 

INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment)
 VALUES (1, 'Snacks 1', 5); 
INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment)
 VALUES (1, 'Snacks 2', 10); 
INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment)
 VALUES (2, 'Snacks 3', 7); 
INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment)
 VALUES (1, 'Snacks 4', 6); 
INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment)
 VALUES (2, 'Snacks 5', 3); 
INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment)
 VALUES (1, 'Snacks 6', 1);
```

The table looks like this:

```
PersonID          Narration          Payment
_____________________________________________
    1             Snacks 1                5
    1             Snacks 2               10
    2             Snacks 3                7
    1             Snacks 4                6
    2             Snacks 5                3
    1             Snacks 6                1
```

Here `PersonID=1` totally spent 22 and `PersonID=2` totally spent 10.

My requirement is to reduce the total `Payment` to be below or equal to 20. There is **no unique columns**. **I wish to delete records to make the total `Payment` below or equal to 20**.

In the above table, `PersonID=1` has a total `Payment` greater than 20, so I need to delete some records to reduce the total payment.

My Expected Output

```
PersonID          Narration          Payment
_____________________________________________

    1             Snacks 2               10
    2             Snacks 3                7
    1             Snacks 4                6
    2             Snacks 5                3
    1             Snacks 6                1
```

Here I removed

```
1             Snacks 1                5
```

Now the total `Payment` of `PersonID=1` is 17, which is below 20.

Based on logic we have to delete the records.

Kindly assist me in both SQL Server and MySQL. My First Preference is SQL Server.

Comment: What would be the expected result here? Also, tag your question with the proper dbms, mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Kindly assist me in both SQL Server and MySQL. My First Preference is SQL Server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Again, please post the expected result.

Comment: I updated the post with expected result.

Comment: Why you removed Snacks 1, but not e.g. Snacks 2 or Snacks 4?

Comment: I need to roundup with 20 or below 20, you can remove any records till the total equal to 20 or lesser than 20, don't repeat if the total reached 20 or lesser than 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one possible variant for SQL Server 2012+.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE Ledger
(
    PersonID int,
    Narration varchar(255),
    Payment int
);

INSERT INTO Ledger(PersonID, Narration, Payment) VALUES 
(1, 'Snacks 1', 5),
(1, 'Snacks 2', 10),
(2, 'Snacks 3', 7),
(1, 'Snacks 4', 6),
(2, 'Snacks 5', 3),
(1, 'Snacks 6', 1);

SELECT *
FROM Ledger
ORDER BY PersonID, Payment;

+----------+-----------+---------+
| PersonID | Narration | Payment |
+----------+-----------+---------+
|        1 | Snacks 6  |       1 |
|        1 | Snacks 1  |       5 |
|        1 | Snacks 4  |       6 |
|        1 | Snacks 2  |      10 |
|        2 | Snacks 5  |       3 |
|        2 | Snacks 3  |       7 |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

**Query**

We can calculate the running total to determine which rows we want to keep and which to delete. You can tune the logic of row selection by choosing the sorting in the running total. In this example I'll calculate the running total starting from the smallest `Payment`, so rows with smallest `Payment` will remain.

This query shows the calculations, to understand how it works:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        PersonID
        ,Narration
        ,Payment
        ,SUM(Payment) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Payment
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ss
    FROM Ledger
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
ORDER BY PersonID, Payment;


+----------+-----------+---------+----+
| PersonID | Narration | Payment | ss |
+----------+-----------+---------+----+
|        1 | Snacks 6  |       1 |  1 |
|        1 | Snacks 1  |       5 |  6 |
|        1 | Snacks 4  |       6 | 12 |
|        1 | Snacks 2  |      10 | 22 |
|        2 | Snacks 5  |       3 |  3 |
|        2 | Snacks 3  |       7 | 10 |
+----------+-----------+---------+----+
```

This query actually deletes rows:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        PersonID
        ,Narration
        ,Payment
        ,SUM(Payment) OVER 
            (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY Payment
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS ss
    FROM Ledger
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE ss > 20;
```

**Result**

```
SELECT *
FROM Ledger
ORDER BY PersonID, Payment;

+----------+-----------+---------+
| PersonID | Narration | Payment |
+----------+-----------+---------+
|        1 | Snacks 6  |       1 |
|        1 | Snacks 1  |       5 |
|        1 | Snacks 4  |       6 |
|        2 | Snacks 5  |       3 |
|        2 | Snacks 3  |       7 |
+----------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Good answer.  Note - if you use order by payment desc you can get as close to 20 without going over.  It was not a stated requirement but it might be desirable to some.

Comment: @JoeC, with ordering by `payment desc` there is a risk to delete all rows, if at least one payment is more than 20. In practice it is rather difficult to determine an "optimal" subset. I think it is called a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem. SQL is not the best way to do it properly.

Comment: Good Answer. Can you please translate this to MySQL please.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan, I don't know how to translate it to MySQL, because it doesn't support window functions. There must be many examples how to calculate running total in MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - If I want to Implement the same logic in MySQL means whats the solution. Kindly give the idea please. I'm not asking CTE in MySQL, I'm asking the logic in MySQL.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov - Thanks a lot.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan, the idea of this query is to calculate a running/cumulative sum of `Payment` amounts partitioned by `PersonID`. Then delete all rows that have cumulative sum greater than the threshold (20).  @IRPunch, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can also the below query to get the required output :-

```
DECLARE @PID int ,@PID1 int,@Narr VARCHAR(250),@Payment decimal(18,2),@Payment1 decimal(18,2),@cnt int

SET @cnt = 20
set @Payment1=0
set @PID1=0

Create table #t1(PersonID int,Narration varchar(250),Payment decimal(18,2));

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT PersonID,Narration,Payment from Ledger order by personid ,Payment

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @PID,@Narr,@Payment   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  
if (@PID1 <> @PID)
BEGIN
SET @Payment1 = 0
END
set @PID1 = @PID
SET @Payment1 = @Payment1 + @Payment

If(@Payment1 <= 20)
begin

Insert into #t1(PersonID,Narration,Payment)
values(@PID,@Narr,@Payment)

end
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @PID,@Narr,@Payment    
end
CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

select * from #t1
order by personid
drop table #t1
```

Tested the same and got below output for below input :-

Input :-

```
1   Snacks 1    5
1   Snacks 2    10
1   Snacks 4    6
1   Snacks 6    1
2   Snacks 5    3
2   Snacks 3    7
3   Snacks 7    15
3   Snacks 8    15
4   Snacks 9    10
```

Output :-

```
 1  Snacks 6    1.00
 1  Snacks 1    5.00
 1  Snacks 4    6.00
 2  Snacks 5    3.00
 2  Snacks 3    7.00
 3  Snacks 7    15.00
 4  Snacks 9    10.00
```