# Average for each row in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, count, sum, average

I would like to ask you guys how to count the average to the results below:

My code looks as follow:

```
SELECT `milestone_id`, `status`, sum(value), 
    CASE WHEN (status !='done') THEN (value ='0') ELSE sum(value) END as val 
FROM project_has_tasks 
WHERE project_id='56' 
AND milestone_id !=0 
GROUP BY milestone_id ASC
```

Results:

```
milestone_id | status | sum(value) | val |
121            done     81           81
122            undone   25           0
123            done     64           64
124            done     23           23
```

What I wanna to do is to put there an average number (as avg) for each row so the results should looks like this:

```
milestone_id | status | sum(value) | val | avg |
121            done     81           81    81
122            undone   25           0     40,5
123            done     64           64    48,3
124            done     23           23    42
```

And so on
The question - How to achieve the results like above?

```
PS:
The average for row 121 is from 81/1 = 81
The average for row 122 is from (81+0)/2 = 40,5
The average for row 123 is from (81+0+64)/3 = 48,3
The average for row 124 is from (81+0+64+23)/4 = 42
```

Comment: Soo much easier to help if we can actually see the query

Comment: @RiggsFolly MySQL allows this.

Comment: @fancyPants _Another good day_ Always learning!! Thanks

Comment: Your status column is neither in the group by clause, nor is an aggregate function applied to it. That makes your query invalid. Also I don't understand how your average is calculated.

Comment: The average e.g for row 124 is from (81+0+64+23)/4 =42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my first time posting so please forgive me if I've left out anything crucial. I've used @ variables in MySQL to achieve something like this before. Hopefully it will help you. I tested this using DB fiddle and since I don't really know how you data is structured I had to simplify a bit. Here is the sample table I created.

```
CREATE TABLE project_has_tasks (`milestone_id` int(6), `status` varchar(100), `value` int(6));

INSERT INTO project_has_tasks (`milestone_id`, `status`, `value`) VALUES (1, 'done', 81);
INSERT INTO project_has_tasks (`milestone_id`, `status`, `value`) VALUES (2, 'undone', 24);
INSERT INTO project_has_tasks (`milestone_id`, `status`, `value`) VALUES (3, 'done', 64);
INSERT INTO project_has_tasks (`milestone_id`, `status`, `value`) VALUES (4, 'done', 23);
```

And here is the query I came up with to generate a rolling average.

```
SELECT milestone_id
       , Status
       , value
       , CASE WHEN (status != 'done') 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE value END AS val
       , (@v_total + CASE WHEN (status != 'done') 
                          THEN 0 
                          ELSE value END) / @v_count AS avg
       , @v_total := @v_total + CASE WHEN (status !='done') 
                                     THEN 0 
                                     ELSE value END
       , @v_count := @v_count + 1
  FROM project_has_tasks, (SELECT @v_total := 0, @v_count := 1) vars;
```

Results:

```
milestone_id | status | value | val | avg    | @v_total... | @v_count...
1            | done   |  81   | 81  | 81     |   81        |  2
2            | undone |  24   |  0  | 40.5   |   81        |  3
3            | done   |  64   | 64  | 48.3...|  145        |  4
4            | done   |  23   | 23  | 42     |  168        |  5
```

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

What you need is to calculate a running average.

This could easily be done by modifying the approach for calculating a running sum:

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290936/1688441

### Example

Create a view:

```
create view temp as 
SELECT `milestone_id`, `status`, sum(value), 
    CASE WHEN (status !='done') THEN (value ='0') ELSE sum(value) END as val 
FROM project_has_tasks 
WHERE project_id='56' 
AND milestone_id !=0 
GROUP BY milestone_id ASC
```

Run the following code:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SET @runcount:=0;
SELECT
  id,
  val,
  (@runtot := @runtot + val) AS runTotal,
  (@runcount := @runcount + 1) AS runCount,
  (@runtot / @runcount) AS runCount
FROM
  temp;
```

### For Testing

Since we don't have your database and tables, could be tested using the following table instead of view:

```
create table temp(id int, val  int);

insert into temp(id, val) values (121, 81);
insert into temp(id, val) values (122, 0);
insert into temp(id, val) values (123, 64);
insert into temp(id, val) values (124, 23);
```