# Oracle SQL Accumulated value for the date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 3 columns: id, date and amount, but I would like to get accumulated SUM for each date (Last column).

[image]

Do you have an easy solution how to add this column?
I am trying with this:

```
SELECT date, sum(amount) as accumulated 
FROM table group by date
WHERE max(date);
```

Should I user OVER() for this?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: *A fortiori*, computing running totals is, in the real world, dependent on the make and model of database server. Here for MySQL:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql

Comment: The syntax of your query is wrong, group by goes after the where clause.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use This:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.DATE, T.AMOUNT, (SELECT SUM(S.AMOUNT) FROM TABLE S WHERE S.DATE=T.DATE) ACCUMULATED
from
table T
```

This will give you the records from the table with a sum for all records for the date.

Comment: I have all the columns in the same table. I am trying to check this.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I don't think you can use s.date, s.amount, from the other selectors? Also "from" is missing in front of table T.

Comment: i missed the from...its added

Comment: Thank you, there is also a dot for t.id. I was however fixing it: 
SELECT transaction.id, transaction.date, transaction.amount, 
(SELECT SUM(rev.amount) FROM maintable rev WHERE rev.date=transaction.date)
FROM maintable transaction;

I hope my syntax is also fine.

Answer (score 2):

Use a window function to the total for each day:

```
SELECT date, 
       amount,
       sum(amount) over (partition by date) as accumulated 
FROM the_table;
```

However this will only work, if your dates all have the same time part (in Oracle a `DATE` column also contains a time). To make sure you ignore the time part, use `trunc()` to make sure all time parts are normalized to `00:00:00`

```
SELECT date, 
       amount,
       sum(amount) over (partition by trunc(date)) as accumulated 
FROM the_table;
```