# MySQL how to create a running total

Tags: mysql

I have some data in table_1:

```
order_id | cust_id | order_date | city_id
101        |    1    | 15/03/2018 |     1001
102        |    1    | 15/03/2018 |     1005
103        |    2    | 10/03/2018 |     1001
104        |    4    | 16/02/2018 |     1006
105        |    4    | 10/01/2018 |     1250
106        |    4    | 15/03/2018 |     1250
107        |    6    | 16/02/2018 |     1058
108        |    6    | 10/03/2018 |     1058
109        |    4    | 23/02/2018 |     1006
110        |    7    | 19/01/2018 |     1005
111        |    7    | 21/01/2018 |     1005
...
```

I have this data in table_2

```
city_id | city_name
  1001  |   New York
  1005  |  London
  1006  |  Brighton
  1250  |  Toronto
  1058  | Manchester
```

I need to find the weekly order count for London for the last 10 weeks, and also the cumulative total.

This is just a subset of the data I'm working with.

So far I've tried this:

```
set @running_total:=0;
select week(a.order_date) as week_start,
    count(a.order_id) as order_count,
    (
        @running_total := @running_total + count(a.order_id)
        ) as cuml_count
from table_1 a
    left join table_2 b on a.city_id = b.city_id
    join (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
where b.city_name = "London"
group by 1
;
```

but the resulting cuml_count matches the order_count. On the data I'm working with it looks like:

```
week_start | order_count | cuml_count
     2     |      1      |      1
     3     |      1      |      1
     10    |      1      |      1
```

It should look like:

```
week_start | order_count | cuml_count
         2     |      1      |      1
         3     |      1      |      2
         10    |      1      |      3
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I've edited the data so my code is now reproducable

Comment: I don't see that.

Comment: That's odd and interesting, it is the first time in 20+ years that I'm seeing someone using a number as alias. Now I will test this and also using it along with the columns numbers in order by just to see what happens!

Comment: Like `select 1.a, 1.b from someTable 1 order by 1`...

Comment: Well, Mysql doesn't accept this syntax. Is this the real query?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I had to hide the actual data and table names, I will replace replace with `select a.order_id, b.city_id from table_1 a, table_2 b` etc.

Comment: Sounds like a task for the OP to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this SO post for the details 
[Calculate a running total in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql)

But something like:

```
SET @running_total:=0;
SELECT 
    week_start, 
    order_count,
    (@running_total := @running_total + order_count) AS cuml_count
FROM (
    SELECT week(t1.order_date) as week_start,
    COUNT(t1.order_date) AS order_count
    FROM table_1 AS t1
        LEFT JOIN
            table_2 AS t2 
            ON t1.city_id = t2.city_id
    WHERE t2.city_name = "London"
    GROUP BY week_start
) AS temp
ORDER BY week_start
```

might work for you

Edit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8f806/5
Created one for OP & added ORDER BY

Edit: Moved to @Strawberry's placement of the ORDER BY, the init in select is also really good too!

Comment: I cannot imagine why an OUTER JOIN would appear in such a query

Comment: I was just meaning to point out that this might be a duplicate question is all. But the formatting is a bit nicer here than in comments

Comment: Unfortunately, the accepted answer on the linked page is flawed. It happens, I'm afraid. This answer perpetuates the error.

Comment: This worked, thanks very much. I've actually tried the other solution linked to but it didn't work.

Comment: @jceg316 If this works, it does so by luck rather than design. A variable rank ALWAYS needs an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Strawberry hmm, good point, there really should be an `order by` in there shouldn't there.

Comment: It's still not correct. Here's a link to a query. I can't say whether it's correct, but it is at least valid: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8f806/7