# Column "f.price" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function, but I've already used window function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns: `date` and `price`. They both aren't unique.

I need to get running total in unique date order (one date - values sum for this date, next date - next sum + previous one and so on).

I know how to do this with subquery, but I want to use window functions:

There is a simple query:

```
SELECT f.date, SUM(f.price) OVER () FROM f GROUP BY f.date
```

It returns the error:

> column `f.price` must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause or be used in an aggregate function

But I've already used aggregate function (`SUM`).

Can somebody tell me why this happend?

Comment: Though this answer is MySQL, I would think the solution you're looking for would be very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664700/calculate-a-running-total-in-mysql

Comment: The 3d anwer is really close, but I've had the error and he hasn't.

Answer (score 0):

try avoiding over()

```
select f.date,
   SUM(f.price) 
from f
group by f.date
```

Comment: In this case I'll get sum for one day without adding the result to the next day result. I need running total.

Comment: you are using a empty over  ..    .. try using an over with a proper content  ..  .. anyway  seems that error iis solved ..

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing window functions and aggregation, which is generally not a good idea. You are getting the error because, indeed, column `f.price` is not used in an aggregate function (it is used a *window* function).

I believe that the following query should give you what you want. It uses a window function, and relies on `DISTINCT` instead of aggregation.

```
SELECT DISTINCT fdate, SUM(fprice) OVER(ORDER BY fdate) FROM f ORDER BY fdate;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/NC7D9FgNmZ2vT38uiGU22/0)**:

Consider the following sample data, that seems to match your spec:

```
| fdate                    | fprice |
| ------------------------ | ------ |
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 1      |
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 2      |
| 2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 3      |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z | 4      |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z | 1      |
```

The query would return:

```
| fdate                    | sum |
| ------------------------ | --- |
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | 3   |
| 2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z | 6   |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00.000Z | 11  |
```